# Does Python support short-circuiting?

Tags: python, boolean-logic, short-circuiting

Does Python support short-circuiting in boolean expressions?

Comment: Closely related: [Strange use of “and” / “or” operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/strange-use-of-and-or-operator)

Answer (score 438, accepted):

Yep, both `and` and `or` operators short-circuit -- see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

Answer (score 269):

#### Short-circuiting behavior in operator `and`, `or`:

Let's first define a useful function to determine if something is executed or not. A simple function that accepts an argument, prints a message and returns the input, unchanged.

```
>>> def fun(i):
...     print "executed"
...     return i
...
```

One can observe the [Python's short-circuiting behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) of `and`, `or` operators in the following example:

```
>>> fun(1)
executed
1
>>> 1 or fun(1)    # due to short-circuiting  "executed" not printed
1
>>> 1 and fun(1)   # fun(1) called and "executed" printed 
executed
1
>>> 0 and fun(1)   # due to short-circuiting  "executed" not printed 
0
```

**Note:** The following values are considered by the interpreter to mean false:

```
        False    None    0    ""    ()    []     {}
```

#### Short-circuiting behavior in function: `any()`, `all()`:

Python's [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) functions also support short-circuiting. As shown in the docs; they evaluate each element of a sequence in-order, until finding a result that allows an early exit in the evaluation. Consider examples below to understand both.

The function [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) checks if any element is True. It stops executing as soon as a True is encountered and returns True.

```
>>> any(fun(i) for i in [1, 2, 3, 4])   # bool(1) = True
executed
True
>>> any(fun(i) for i in [0, 2, 3, 4])   
executed                               # bool(0) = False
executed                               # bool(2) = True
True
>>> any(fun(i) for i in [0, 0, 3, 4])
executed
executed
executed
True
```

The function [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) checks all elements are True and stops executing as soon as a False is encountered:

```
>>> all(fun(i) for i in [0, 0, 3, 4])
executed
False
>>> all(fun(i) for i in [1, 0, 3, 4])
executed
executed
False
```

#### Short-circuiting behavior in Chained Comparison:

Additionally, in Python

> [Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons); for example, `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

```
>>> 5 > 6 > fun(3)    # same as:  5 > 6 and 6 > fun(3)
False                 # 5 > 6 is False so fun() not called and "executed" NOT printed
>>> 5 < 6 > fun(3)    # 5 < 6 is True 
executed              # fun(3) called and "executed" printed
True
>>> 4 <= 6 > fun(7)   # 4 <= 6 is True  
executed              # fun(3) called and "executed" printed
False
>>> 5 < fun(6) < 3    # only prints "executed" once
executed
False
>>> 5 < fun(6) and fun(6) < 3 # prints "executed" twice, because the second part executes it again
executed
executed
False
```

**Edit:**
One more interesting point to note **:-** Logical [`and`, `or`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) operators in Python returns an operand's **value** instead of a Boolean (`True` or `False`). For example:

> Operation `x and y` gives the result `if x is false, then x, else y`

<sup>Unlike in other languages e.g. `&&`, `||` operators in C that return either 0 or 1.</sup>

Examples:

```
>>> 3 and 5    # Second operand evaluated and returned 
5                   
>>> 3  and ()
()
>>> () and 5   # Second operand NOT evaluated as first operand () is  false
()             # so first operand returned
```

Similarly `or` operator return left most value for which `bool(value)` == `True` else right most false value (according to short-circuiting behavior), examples:

```
>>> 2 or 5    # left most operand bool(2) == True
2    
>>> 0 or 5    # bool(0) == False and bool(5) == True
5
>>> 0 or ()
()
```

So, how is this useful? One example is given in [Practical Python](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=KmKoNJ2OoOYC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=zip%28range%285%29,%20xrange%28100000000%29%29&source=bl&ots=-BxWZinKHq&sig=O9G4mskHmYDljCCQv8v7alVUy_M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0mMPUoa9LsXJrAe7p4DABA&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=zip%28range%285%29,%20xrange%28100000000%29%29&f=false) By Magnus Lie Hetland:
Let’s say a user is supposed to enter his or her name, but may opt to enter nothing, in which case you want to use the default value `'<Unknown>'`.
You could use an if statement, but you could also state things very succinctly:

```
In [171]: name = raw_input('Enter Name: ') or '<Unknown>'
Enter Name: 

In [172]: name
Out[172]: '<Unknown>'
```

In other words, if the return value from `raw_input` is true (not an empty string), it is assigned to name (nothing changes); otherwise, the default `'<Unknown>'` is assigned to `name`.

Comment: Minor quibble: The explicit list of falsy values is slightly misleading. *Any* type can have one or more falsy values. By convention, all numeric types with value `0` are falsy (so it's not just `0`, it's `0.0`, `0j`, `decimal.Decimal(0)`, `fractions.Fraction(0)`, etc.), as are all collections with length `0` (so on top of what you listed, `b''` [Py3], `u''` [Py2] and `set()`/`frozenset()` are all built-ins that evaluate as falsy), but user-defined/third-party types can define their own (with `__bool__` [Py3]/`__nonzero__` [Py2] directly, or indirectly by defining `__len__`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger here your comment will complete my answer. thanks for adding this note.

Comment: Also, python double-evaluates short circuited conditionals, if later used as booleans... unless they are in an if statement, which is priviliged: https://gist.github.com/earonesty/08e9cbe083a5e0583feb8a34cc538010

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan does python support long circuit?

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran :( sorry I do not know about that. If you post a new question then please share with me.

Comment: There is a caveat when using all, in that it won't behave exactly like chaining booleans using and expressions. It will evaluate everything in the list. This can cause confusion when relying on expressions that **must** short circuit to avoid raising an exception. For example: If `n = len(nums)` and `i >= n`, then `i < n and nums[i] > 0` would not raise an exception, yet `all([i < n, nums[i] > 0])` would raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: @sjking your expressions are not equal, in `all()` you are forcing `nums[i] > 0]` to evaluate in a list

Answer (score 63):

Yes. Try the following in your python interpreter:

and

```
>>>False and 3/0
False
>>>True and 3/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

or

```
>>>True or 3/0
True
>>>False or 3/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: How can one do something like `myVar == 5 and continue`? It seems to not be valid.