# Is it safe to refer to a possibly nonexistant variable after a check in an if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, logic, boolean

Say I have a myObject class with a member called prop. I have a variable var which may or may not be a myObject. I want to check if prop holds a certain value, and if so, do something, and if it doesn't, or var is not a myObject, do nothng.

Would it be safe to do the following:

```
if isinstance(var, myObject) and var.prop == 10:
    #Do something
```

Basically, is it guaranteed that the second part of that if statement will not be checked if the first part evaluates to False? If it is checked even if var is not a myObject, an error will be thrown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python support short-circuiting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Comment: Pretty much, yup! Didn't know the term used for this (short-circuting). Feel free to delete/close if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, `and` short circuits. [But I wouldn't do it that way](http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/). A better method is to use `hasattr` or a `try, except` block.

```
if hasattr(var, 'prop') and var.prop == 10:
    print var.prop
```

Or (if it's unusual for a propless var to come along):

```
try:
    print var.prop
except AttributeError:
    print "propless var"
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know, and really useful information about isinstance(). Thanks!