# in OR condition which side evaluate first in python?

Tags: python, performance

```
if cpu_expensive_condition() or simple_condition():
        do_something()
```

out of two condition in OR statement in above python code which will be evaluate first ? , and is it compulsory that both will be evaluate ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Quoted from [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Answer (score 6):

Python evaluates from left to right, and both sides do not need to be evaluated. Consider the following example.

```
def left(x):
    print 'left'
    return x

def right(x):
    print 'right'
    return x

if left(False) or right(False):
    print 'Done'

if left(True) or right(True):
    print 'Done'
```

This will produce the following output:

```
left
right #This is where the first if statement ends.
left
Done  #Only the left side was evaluated
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [Boolean Operations — and, or, not](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not) in the Python documentation:

> This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is False.

So `cpu_expensive_condition()` will *always* be evaluated. `simple_condition()` will only be evaluated when `cpu_expensive_condition()` returns `False` (or something that evaluates to `False`, such as `0` or `''` or `None`).

See also: [Does Python support short-circuiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 1):

Python does short-circuit evaluation. Of course the first statement will be evaluated first. The second will only be evaluated if the first is `False` or false-ish.