# Check if all numbers in a list are same sign in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sign

How can I tell if a list (or iterable) of numbers all have the same sign?

Here's my first (naive) draft:

```
def all_same_sign(list):

    negative_count = 0

    for x in list:
        if x < 0:
            negative_count += 1

    return negative_count == 0 or negative_count == len(list)
```

Is there a more pythonic and/or correct way of doing this? First thing that comes to mind is to stop iterating once you have opposite signs.

**Update**

I like the answers so far although I wonder about performance.  I'm not a performance junkie but I think when dealing with lists it's reasonable to consider the performance.  For my particular use-case I don't think it will be a big deal but for completeness of this question I think it's good to address it.  My understanding is the min and max functions have O(n) performance.  The two suggested answers so far have O(2n) performance whereas my above routine adding a short circuit to quit once an opposite sign is detected will have at worst O(n) performance.  Thoughts?

Comment: `O(n)` and `O(2n)` are exactly the same thing. Any algorithm for this problem will have `o(n)` worst-case performance since it'll have to examine each element. Finally, if you care about performance, I urge you to benchmark the candidate approaches on your typical data.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can make use of `all` function: -

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> all(item >= 0 for item in x) or all(item < 0 for item in x)
True
```

Don't know whether it's the most pythonic way.

Comment: Does python have signed zeros?

Comment: @mgilson. Actually, I've no idea. I've a very little experience in Python. :(

Answer (score 16):

How about:

```
same_sign = not min(l) < 0 < max(l)
```

Basically, this checks whether the smallest element of `l` and the largest element straddle zero.

This doesn't short-circuit, but does avoid Python loops. Only benchmarking can tell whether this is a good tradeoff for your data (and whether the performance of this piece even matters).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `all` you could use `any`, as it short-circuits on the first true item as well:

```
same = lambda s: any(i >= 0 for i in s) ^ any(i < 0 for i in s)
```

Comment: I don't understand.  `all` short-circuits on the first `False`; any short-circuits on the first `True`.

Comment: I believe `all` also short-circuits see the comment on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2580142/155268

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to using `all`, you can use `any`, which has the benefit of better performance, as it will break the loop on the first occurrence of different sign:

```
def all_same_sign(lst):
    if lst[0] >= 0:
        return not any(i < 0 for i in lst)
    else:
        return not any(i >= 0 for i in lst)
```

It would be a little tricky if you want to consider 0, as belonging to both groups:

```
def all_same_sign(lst):
    first = 0
    i = 0
    while first == 0:
        first = lst[i]
        i += 1
    if first > 0:
        return not any(i < 0 for i in lst)
    else:
        return not any(i > 0 for i in lst)
```

In any case, you iterate the list once instead of twice as in other answers. Your code has the drawback of iterating the loop in Python, which is much less efficient than using built-in functions.

Comment: great point didn't think about the difference between the iteration happening in python vs using a built-in.