# Python - logical evaluation order in "if" statement

Tags: python, boolean, short-circuiting

In Python we can do this:

```
if True or blah:
    print("it's ok") # will be executed

if blah or True: # will raise a NameError
    print("it's not ok")

class Blah:
    pass
blah = Blah()

if blah or blah.notexist:
    print("it's ok") # also will be executed
```

- Can somebody point me to documentation on this feature?
- Is it an implementation detail or feature of the language?
- Is it good coding style to exploit this feature?

Comment: The `blah or True` one does not raise an exception for me, it prints.

Comment: @TimS.: only if you define `blah` *first*. Note that `blah` is *not yet defined* at the top of the example, so a `NameError` is raised instead.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `or` and `and` *short circuit*, see the [Boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) documentation:

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Note how, for `and`, `y` is *only* evaluated if `x` evaluates to a True value. Inversely, for `or`, `y` is only evaluated if `x` evaluated to a False value.

For the first expression `True or blah`, this means that `blah` is never evaluated, since the first part is already `True`.

Furthermore, your custom `Blah` class is considered True:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. (See the [`__nonzero__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) special method for a way to change this.)

Since your class does not implement a `__nonzero__()` method (nor a `__len__` method), it is considered `True` as far as boolean expressions are concerned.

In the expression `blah or blah.notexist`, `blah` is thus true, and `blah.notexist` is never evaluated.

This feature is used quite regularly and effectively by experienced developers, most often to specify defaults:

```
some_setting = user_supplied_value or 'default literal'
object_test = is_it_defined and is_it_defined.some_attribute
```

Do be wary of chaining these and use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) instead where applicable.

Answer (score 7):

This is called short-circuiting and is a feature of the language:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions

> The Boolean operators `and` and `or` are so-called short-circuit operators: their arguments are evaluated from left to right, and evaluation stops as soon as the outcome is determined. For example, if A and C are true but B is false, A and B and C does not evaluate the expression C. When used as a general value and not as a Boolean, the return value of a short-circuit operator is the last evaluated argument.

Answer (score 3):

It's the way the operators logical operators, specifically `or` in python work: **short circuit evaluation.**

To better explain it, consider the following:

```
if True or False:
    print('True') # never reaches the evaluation of False, because it sees True first.

if False or True:
    print('True') # print's True, but it reaches the evaluation of True after False has been evaluated.
```

For more information see the following:

- [The official python documentation on boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not)
- [A stack overflow question regarding short circuitry in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 2):

With the `or` operator, values are evaluated from left to right. After one value evaluates to `True`, the entire statement evaluates to `True` (so no more values are evaluated).

- [Official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not)
- It's a feature of the language
- There is nothing wrong with using its functionality