# Why do I get 0 when I run "0 and True" or "0 and False"

Tags: python, boolean-expression

consider this code:

```
>>> 0 and True
0
>>> 0 and False
0
```

Why do I get `0` when I run the above commands in Python?

Comment: It's called short-circuiting.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - logical evaluation order in "if" statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069517/python-logical-evaluation-order-in-if-statement)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the first condition of an `and` evaluates to `False` (which 0 does in Python), the second argument is not evaluated at all, because the `and` will never become true. This is called short-circuiting. In that case, the result of the expression is the first operand, in your case 0.

Answer (score 2):

Because `0` is a false value (all numeric 0 values are, as well as empty containers, and `None` and `False`).

The `and` operator short-curcuits; if the left-hand expression evaluates to a false value, it is returned, otherwise the right-hand expression outcome is returned.

The `or` operator does the same, but for a true left-hand value; `1 or False` returns `1`.

From the [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) documentation:

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

You can make handy use of this:

```
foo = None
if something_or_other:
    foo = lambda arg: arg * 3

outcome = foo and foo('bar')
outcome = foo or expensive_call()
```

where `foo` is only called if it is actually defined and not still `None`; the `expensive_call()` is only invoked if `foo` is not yet bound to a true value.

Answer (score 0):

You are ANDing with zero. You should get zero always.

Comment: That's true of bitwise `&`, but the answer is a little more intricate (and Python-specific) with boolean `and`.

Answer (score 0):

this is because, logical operators are evaluated from left to right. So, for `or` if True find rest of the expression not evaluated:

```
>>> True or "one"
True
>>> False or "one"
'one'
```

Similarly for `and`, if False found rest of the expression ignored:

```
>>> True and "one"
'one'
>>> False and "one"
False
```

In compiler design, this concept is called short-circuiting and this is same design for most of compilers.

Answer (score 0):

most of programming languages have this feature, it's fast branch detection, in your case `and` if first condition is false, evaluation is fail and second (other) condition never check
in other case `or` if first condition return true second (other) condition never check and result will be true
it's really cool feature look this sample for example:

```
if( list != null and !list.isEmpty() ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

if this feature does not exists this `if` statement cause exception, but now `!list.isEmpty()` will never runs when `list` is `null`

Comment: Note that while many languages short-circuit, returning the first operand (if false) or the second (if the first is true) is a somewhat Python-specific feature.  Java, for instance, short-circuits as well, but always returns `true` or `false`, not a truth-y value (since Java doesn't have such a concept).