# How are conditional statements with multiple conditions evaluated?

Tags: python

I'd expect the following two code blocks to be evaluated the same way, but it would seem that is not the case. For example, with this:

```
if True or False and False:
    print('True')                                                               
else:                                                                           
    print('False')
```

True is printed. But with this:

```
if (True or False) and False:
    print('True')
else:                                                                           
    print('False')
```

False is printed. Here's my breakdown of the logic:

- `True or False` = `True`
- `True and False` = `False`

By substitution, `(True or False) and False` = `True and False` = `False`.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Per the Python 2.x and 3.x docs, the `and` operator has higher precedence than the `or` operator. Also, have a look at the boolean truth table:

[image]

That means in your expression:

```
if True or False and False:
```

In the expression, `False and False` is grouped together because of precedence. That means Python evaluates it as:

```
if True or (False and False):
```

Now, it's evaluated left to right. Since the first condition is `True`, it short-circuits and skips the second condition and evaluates to `True` printing 'True'. (This short-circuits because if the first side is true, it *has to be true*.)

Now in your second example:

```
if (True or False) and False:
```

This makes `True or False` evaluate first, which gives `True`. Then it does `True and False` which is `False`, printing 'False'.

```
>>> print(True or False)
True
>>> print(True and False)
False
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with short-circuiting. Non-short-circuit evaluation would have produced the same outcome.

Comment: You're still saying nothing about precedence. By the logic of your answer, `False and True or True` would be `False`.

Comment: @user2357112 I've updated the answer to include correct information. Thanks for pointing out the misinformation and criticism, very much appreciated!

Comment: Well, you fixed the precedence issues, but now your answer is using the wrong evaluation order. Precedence only controls argument grouping, not evaluation order; the expression is still evaluated left-to-right and short-circuited.

Comment: @user2357112 Right again. Updated :)

Answer (score 1):

`(True or False)` evaluates to `True`. Therefore `(True or False) and False` evaluates to `True and False`, which evaluates to `False`.

This answer explains the rules for boolean evaluation quite well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069560/1470749

Answer (score 1):

Standard Order of operations gives `and` precedence over `or`, so the first statement  `True or False and False` is logically equivalent to

```
True or (False and False)
```

This evaluates to `True`.

The second statement is

```
(True or False) and False
```

This evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

The first condition returns false. You know that a value of false will not run the code block below it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).