# Order of Evaluation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

```
k = 10 / 3
l = k <= 3 or True
```

The value for l in this code returns True. How is this possible? In the order of evaluation, comparisons are higher prioritised than the "or, not, and" operators.

Comment: I'm duping this to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069517/python-logical-evaluation-order-in-if-statement in which a great top answer exists to complement my short one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do have a higher priority, but, the [`or` operator works by](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Since `k` is `3.3333333333333335`, the expression `k <= 3` is `False`, `True` is going to be evaluated (to itself) and returned making `l == True`.