# IndexError: index out of bounds when using 'and' operators

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create support and resistance for the stocks chart. However, I got this error.
Here is my code:

```
def isResistance(df,i):
    resistance = df['High'][i] > df['High'][i-1]  and df['High'][i] > df['High'][i+1] \
    and df['High'][i] > df['High'][i+2] and df['High'][i] > df['High'][i-2] \
    and df['High'][i] > df['High'][i+3] and df['High'][i] > df['High'][i-3] 
    
    return resistance
```

And I'm trying to take all of the list of the support and resistance by using this:

```
levels = []
for i in range(2,df.shape[0]-2):
    
    if isSupport(df,i):
        levels.append((i,df['Low'][i]))
    elif isResistance(df,i):
        levels.append((i,df['High'][i]))
```

Then the error occurs in this part:

```
and df['High'][i] > df['High'][i+3] and df['High'][i] > df['High'][i-3]
```

However, in this code there is no any errors:

```
def isSupport(df,i):
    support = df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i-1]  and df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i+1] \
    and df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i+2] and df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i-2] \
    and df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i+3] and df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i-3]
    
    return support
```

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Assuming df is a Pandas dataframe, shouldn't it be possible to do this with a lot less code by leveraging some sort of slice + broadcast? Something like `all(df['High'][i] > df['High'][i-3:i+4])`  (except I'm not sure at all how Pandas slices work...)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the logic are executed in order, that is,

for `a and b and c`, a will be evaluated first, then b, and lastly c. If a is `False`, b and c won't be executed and checked.

Therefore, in your case, since the clauses before `df['High'][i] > df['High'][i+3] and df['High'][i] > df['High'][i-3]` may evaluated to be `False`, the execution of this logic chain ended and will not evaluate the statement that has `IndexError`. But if they all evaluated to be `True`, the statement that has `IndexError` will be evaluated and thus throw an error to you.

To fix it, you can simply put one more clause before it, `len(df['High']) >= 3`, to take advantage of this logic chain evaluation order and stop it from accessing invalid index. Or I will just rewrite it to be a longer `if` statement for a cleaner code.

more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069560/12569596) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)