# How to check if a input is in binary format(1 and 0)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have made a program however I wanted to add an exception if the user inputs is not in a binary format. I have tried many times adding exceptions but I can't seem to get it to work. The below is the program code. I would appreciate if someone could help.

```
import time
error=True
n=0
while n!=1:
    print"***Welcome to the Bin2Dec Converter.***\n"
    while error:
        try:
            bin2dec =raw_input("Please enter a binary number: ")
            error=False
        except NameError: 
            print"Enter a Binary number. Please try again.\n"
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except SyntaxError: 
            print"Enter a Binary number. Please try again.\n"
            time.sleep(0.5)


        #converts bin2dec
        decnum = 0 
        for i in bin2dec: 
            decnum = decnum * 2 + int(i)
            time.sleep(0.25)
        print decnum, "<<This is your answer.\n" #prints output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are avoiding Python's built in way of doing this (`int(..., 2)`), as a learning exercise, then a logical and Pythonic approach would be to make your own error class and build the error checking in to your conversion function.

```
class BinaryError(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Not a valid binary number"

def bin2dec(input_string):
    r = 0
    for character in input_string:
        if character == '0':
            r = r * 2
        elif character == '1':
            r = r * 2 + 1
        else:
            raise BinaryError()
    return r

while True:
    try:
        print bin2dec(raw_input("Please enter a binary number: "))
    except BinaryError:
        print "Enter a Binary number. Please try again.\n"
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 9):

Better to ask for forgiveness. Try to convert it to integer using [`int(value, 2)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
while True:
    try:
        decnum = int(raw_input("Please enter a binary number: "), 2)
    except ValueError:
        print "Enter a Binary number. Please try again.\n"
    else:
        break

print decnum
```

Comment: Yup - much more filled out than my answer :)

Comment: I think it would be prettier to get rid of the useless `continue` and maybe move `break` into an `else` block.

Comment: This clearly demonstrates how to convert a binary number to decimal in Python (+1), but it's not what the OP asked...

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, it's an implicit check (converting only works for binary input), so this is kind of what the OP asked + a better way to handle the problem IMO

Comment: Note that this function allows more valid inputs than the OP's version. You should check whether the user input contains a `b` before calling `int(..., 2)`, otherwise inputs starting with the `0b` prefix will be allowed(which I believe is not something the OP wants, and anyway he should be aware of this change).

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, if i could request someone to put the above in the context of my code. I'm still a beginer at python coding. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`int(bin2dec, 2)` will throw a ValueError if the input isn't in binary format. But of course that solves the whole problem for you.

Answer (score 5):

Using `set()`:

```
def is_binary(x):
    return set(input_string) <= set('01')

input_string = "0110110101"
print(is_binary(input_string))

input_string = "00220102"
print(is_binary(input_string))
```

Comment: Note, this won't work for "00000" or "111111" (or any other pattern containing just one of the two characters).

Comment: I think you could write `set(input_string) <= set('01')` http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

Comment: @Septi if you really wanted to use a set for this, then another way is  `not set('01').symmetric_difference(input_string)`

Comment: Another option: `is_binary = set('01').issuperset`. This works on strings.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
>>> b = '01011'
>>> all(c in '01' for c in b) # OR  c in ('0', '1')
True
>>> b = '21011'
>>> all(c in '01' for c in b) # OR  c in ('0', '1')
False
```

Comment: is it faster than others?

Comment: I mean because  [`any()` and `all()` functions also support short-circuiting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting/14892812#14892812)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, I'm not sure. But I think `int` will also stop if it found some invalid character/digit inside loop.

Comment: Ok `int(your_string, 2)` looks more proper way too...thanks to add a technique

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, See [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/longobject.c)  (esp. `PyLong_FromString`)

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this (i.e. if it's not a stupid homework exercise) is using `int(your_string, 2)` and catching `ValueError` which is raised if the string contains an invalid character.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> b = '01011'
>>> not(b.translate(None, '01'))
True
>>> b = '21011'
>>> not(b.translate(None, '01'))
False
```

Comment: `not` is a unary operator, so you don't need to add parenthesis as for a function call.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> matches = re.match('[01]*$', bin2dec)
>>> if matches:
...    process(bin2dec)
```

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, I agree with the `$`; I always forget `match` has an implicit `^`, but not a `$`. `*` vs `+` is a question for the OP really.