# Check if condition matches multiple variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements

I have a method/function that get's passed several variables that possibly have None value. How can I check all variables for None value and replace it with a string in the most pythonic way possible?

Example code:

```
def logData(self, var1=None, var2=None, var3=None):
    if var1 is None:
         var1 = "---"
    if var2 is None:
         var2 = "---"
    if var3 is None:
         var3 = "---"

    # what I would prefer / pseudo code:
    if list(var1, var2, var3) is None:
         list[1] = "---"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var1, var2, var3 = (a or '---' for a in [var1, var2, var3])
```

Comment: @markrages this check is usually added when vars are mutabe, i think for integer it is not needed... but yes, this way im cant handle 0, condition should be changed to something like in superjump answer

Comment: I am new to this method, can you explain exactly what each step does?

Comment: @DominicM meaning of `a or '---'`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting. Remains is tuple unpacking and list comprehension

Answer (score 2):

Use tuple unpacking:

```
var1, var2, var3 = ['---' if (x is None) else x for x in (var1, var2, var3)]
```

Comment: Seems complicated to me, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @DominicM Here's a simple example of tuple unpacking:
   
   # set var1 to 1, var2 to 2 and var3 to 3
   var1, var2, var3 = 1, 2, 3
   # now imagine that your function is called with parameters
   # var1 == 0, var2 == None and var3 = 5, the list comprehension
   # below:

Comment: @DominicM. Whoops, haven't got the hang of commenting yet. What I was trying to say was that, the list comp in the answer iterates through the values passed to your function, (var1, var2, var3), and if any of them are `None` replaces them with '---', otherwise they are left unchanged. Further, the list comp evaluates to three values which are assigned sequentially to variable names on the left, in this case var1, var2, var3.

Comment: Editing the answer might be more appropriate when adding more info to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve this by using `**kwargs`:

```
def logData(self, **kwargs):
  for key,value in kwargs.iteritems():
    if value is None:
      # do assignment ...
```

Comment: Would you call the function same way, passing arguments individually?