# And/Or operator between two objects in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to maintain a python package which was no longer updated since 2008. I guess the Python version the developer used back then was 2.3 or 2.4, I guess. Mostly the source code is the same, but I found something like:

```
fsa = (fsa and union(fsa, fsa2)) or fsa2
```

where `fsa`, `fsa2`, `union(fsa, fsa2)` are all objects. I have no idea how they work to return the new object. Could somebody please give me some hint? Also, Are these operators still allowed in Python 2.7? If no, how do I change it to make it work properly in Python 2.7?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your one line is equivalent of this two ifs:

```
if fsa:
    fsa = union(fsa, fsa2):

if not fsa:
    fsa = fsa2
```

This way (`fsa = (fsa and union(fsa, fsa2)) or fsa2`) of using boolean operators is called **short-circuiting**.

There is some info in [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) and relevant questions, for example: [Does Python support short-circuiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at this page in the documentation: http://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator

In older versions of Python the "and-or" idiom was used to emulate a ternary operator. In modern Python you'd write the above expression as

```
fsa = union(fsa, fsa2) if fsa else fsa2
```

The trick is the short-cutting behaviour of `and` and `or` in Python:

- `a and b` evaluates to `b` if `a` as a boolean evaluates to `True`, otherwise it evaluates to `a`
- `a or b` evaluates to `b` if `a` as a boolean evaluates to `False`, otherwise it evaluates to `a`

Put this together and you have a nice ternary operator emulation :)

EDIT: However, as Alfe rightfully commented, this is not exactly equivalent. If `union(fsa, fsa2)` is `False` as a boolean (i.e. if the `union` function returned `None`) the existing code would return `fsa2` while the "modern" code would return `None` or whatever false value `union` returned. I'd stick with the existing code since it continues to work in newer python versions and document it. Have a look at the implementation of `union` to decide whether you want to transition to the modern, IMHO cleaner, syntax.

Comment: This is probably what is intended by that `and` ... `or` idiom, but it is not exactly the same as the ternary.  If `union(fsa, fsa2)` returns a _falsy_ value, the result will be `fsa2`, regardless of the value of `fsa`.

Answer (score 2):

`and` and `or` each return one of their operands.  `and` returns the first which is *falsy* (or the last if none is), `or` returns the first which is *truthy* (or the last if none is).

*Falsy* and *truthy* refer to the boolean value of the object; empty strings, empty arrays etc. all are *falsy*.