# Boolean logic in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone help to explain the following:

```
1 and 5
5 and 1
```

The above gives `5` and `1` respectively.  Q1: Why is the `and` operator not commutative?

Next:

```
1==True # gives True
```

However:

```
5==True
5==False
```

both give `False`.  Q2: Why?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html section 5.1 says "... All other values are considered True", so 5 should be True.

Comment: In answer to Q2: `bool(5)` is True, this does not mean that `5 == True`

Comment: As shown above, 5 is **`neither`** True nor False.  I am fine with that if that is so defined.  But this clearly contradicts section 5.1.

Comment: @OldGeezer `true != True`, true here means truthy value.

Comment: Dups: [Why do 'and' & 'or' return operands in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598547/why-do-and-or-return-operands-in-python) and [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante)

Comment: Please keep your posts limited to **one** question; you asked two, and both are duplicates. I've closed this as a duplicate of one of those, but Ashwini named the other as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I couldn't find in the text any mention of the `bool()` function.  Can you point me to it in case I am missing something.

Comment: See [*Truth value testing*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) and the [`bool()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression **x and y** first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression **x or y** first evaluates *x*; if *x* is true, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Note that here, `if x is false` means `if bool(x) == False`.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the English text `if x is false` means `if bool(x)==False`.  However, if I treat 5 as neither True nor False, then the definition of `and`: if x is false then x else y also explains why `5 and 1` gives 1 and `1 and 5` gives 5.

Comment: The `bool(x)` distinction is important however, especially if you consider examples like `[] and 5` (that returns `[]`) or the fact that you can define a `__bool__` method (or `__nonzero__` in python 2) to customize boolean evaluation for a class.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question about `and` is that the result of the `and` is the value of the first expression if it is False-like (0, False, None, etc.), otherwise it is the value of the second expression.  A bunch of programming languages share this sort of construct; in some languages like Bash and Perl it's idiomatic to rely on it extensively.  In Python we mostly use `and` for regular boolean logic and rely on it less often for short-circuiting.

As for `1==True` being true but `5==True` being false, well, frankly I wish `1==True` also returned false but obviously it's too late to change it now.  :)

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your second part:

It's true that all non-zero integers are "Truthy" but this does not mean that `5 == True` will return `True`. The `==` operator is comparing value and, when comparing values, 5 is not equal to `True`. If you compare `bool(5) == True` then that will return `True`. When you do `if 5:` what you actually are doing is `if bool(5):`.

The reason that `1 == True` returns `True` is that in Python the `boolean` class is a subclass of `int`, with `True` being represented by `1` and `False` being represented by `0`. So `1 == True` returns True *because they are equal.*

**Note that, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2764017/3005188), this is NOT GUARANTEED in Python 2.x as `True` and `False` can be re-defined.** In Python 3.x they are keywords which will always be equal to 1 and 0, respectively.