# Why does the PHP code function differently than the Python code?

Tags: php, python, computer-science

## PHP program

```
$x = (False or 123)
echo $x
```

## python code

```
x= (False or 123)
print(x)
```

In php answer is `1` and in python answer is `123`.

Why is that?

Comment: In PHP, $x will be boolean true if either `False` or `123` equates to true, false if they are both false.... `False` is False, but `123` equates to True by loose typing, so $x will be boolean true.... and echoing a boolean true displays as `1`.... if you var_dumped instead, you'd see it as a boolean true

Comment: what about python??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP: $x = (False or 123).  False is false(!), 123 is true, false or true == true, so $x get true (or 1 when you print it.

Python: does or operation first, then assigns result to x.  int(False) is 0, int(123) is 123, so it gets 123.  In Python, there is a trick were the or return value is the value that made it true, and not the boolean result.  See this page: 
 http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but `$x = (False or 123)`... look at those brackets!

Comment: Much appreciated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python `and` and `or` do a "McCarthy evaluation" that returns the last value, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22598675/196206 or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

PHP does also short circuit evaluation but only a boolean value is always returned: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am interested in the results that two code segments returns and I am looking for the reason behind the results.