# Problem with understanding of [] and {} or 1

Tags: python

What is the correct thinking about the syntax?

```py
[] and {} or 1
```

Result of this code is `1`
I am not sure how to explain this example.

I tried understanding `[] and {}` and this return `[]`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598547/why-do-and-or-return-operands-in-python).

Comment: One should also point out [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#summary) and Python's left-to-right evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order of operations, `and` comes before `or`, so the effective statement is

```
([] and {}) or 1
```

`bool([])` is False.

`bool({})` is False.

Therefore, `[] and {}` is `[]`.

Finally, `[] or 1` is 1.

Comment: `[] and {}` is `[]`, not `False`.

Comment: And thus `[] or 1` is 1.