# Why does 'x or y' not return a Boolean value?

Tags: python

Recently I have stumbled across an [interesting piece of code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224365/implement-minceraft) in Python

```
condition and 'string1' or 'string2'
```

It took me some time to figure out its meaning but in the end it is another way to write a ternary expression

```
'string1' if condition else 'string2'
```

This made me realise `x or y` does not return True or False but x if x is True and y otherwise ([Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)).

However, I don't see the reason why Python was designed that way. I've seen some use cases in checking for None

```
y = None
x = y or default
```

but this can be easily and clearer achieved using the following

```
x = y if y else default
```

Runtime-wise I also don't see the benefit since, if x is False, the second term in `x or y` needs to be evaluated at some point.

And in terms of code readability I would expect `bool_test = x or y` to contain a Boolean value.

So overall, why was Python designed in that way?

Comment: `y is None` is really only useful for explicitly. Otherwise, `if y:` would suffice. If you want a bool use `bool()`

Comment: This is really a matter of personal (namely, Guido van Rossum's) opinion.

Comment: There was a time (pre 2.5) when the ternary operator `a = b if c else d` wasn't available. Shorthand like `x = y or z` served as a substitute. It's hard to think of a good justification for that old approach now.

Comment: @JamieDeith There wasn't really a justification for it at the time, either; it was just a mostly-but-not-entirely-correct idiom that people latched on to in the absence of an actual conditional expression.

Comment: Partly your questin is about boolean expression short-circuiting - e.g. `if x() or y():` if `x()` returns something truthy then the rest of the expression *won’t* be evaluated, i.e. `y()` won’t be called. Similarly for `if x() and y():` if `x()` is falsy then `y()` won’t be evaluated because there’s no point.

Comment: @barny I understand the usefulness of the short-circuiting but I was really wondering why if x() returns something truthy then why would ```x() or y()``` not simply return True?

Comment: @shiningPanther because the truthiness of the value is just to be used in comparison of the logical operator, not for a value to be returned. Think like this -> `x()` and `y()` both has to FIRST return a value, and then, based on the value, used it in comparison of the `or`. If it is truthy, great, choose it and return it. If they are falsy, then too bad, does not, operation stops.

Comment: @Tomerikoo that answer explains far more perfectly than my comment

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks, I've edited it since I only added it for explicity indeed and don't want the question to be misleading into the truthiness of different Python expressions.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I understand how the Boolean operators are working but was really wondering what is the benefit of their behaviour.

Comment: Well that is really a design choice that is better directed at the designers. Here, we can mostly guess...

Comment: Related: [Why do 'and' & 'or' return operands in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22598547/4518341) (this might be a duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you are right, when we talk about logical operators - `and` and `or`, it should return a boolean - especially if you come from a strictly-typed language.

The thing is, dynamically typed (and often, scripted language) tend to have a wide range of truthiness, aka to evaluate the value of an expression if its TRUE or FALSE. One good example is that in *MOST* languages, evaluates zero, aka `0` as `FALSE`, and it is often implied that way.

Just that - in Python - there are whole lots of things that can be evaluated into `FALSE`, not just an integer of value `0`. Empty lists, empty dictionaries, etc, often are implied as **falsy** aka if you do `if []` -> its the same as `if len(my_array)==0` which your length of array/lists is 0 and end up giving you a nice Boolean `False`.

You can take a look at the truthy table of python [here](https://adamloving.com/2019/09/24/python-truth-table/)

| Value | Truthiness |
| --- | --- |
| `True` | ✅ TRUE |
| `False` | ❌ FALSE |
| `1` | ✅ TRUE |
| `0` | ❌ FALSE |
| `-1` | ✅ TRUE |
| `"True"` | ✅ TRUE |
| `"False"` | ✅ TRUE |
| `"1"` | ✅ TRUE |
| `"0"` | ✅ TRUE |
| `"-1"` | ✅ TRUE |
| `""` | ❌ FALSE |
| `None` | ❌ FALSE |
| `inf` | ✅ TRUE |
| `-inf` | ✅ TRUE |
| `[]` | ❌ FALSE |
| `{}` | ❌ FALSE |
| `[[]]` | ✅ TRUE |
| `[0]` | ✅ TRUE |
| `[1]` | ✅ TRUE |

Readability wise - I think its subjective. `x = y or default` is definitely shorter than say, you know:

```
x = y if y is not None else default
```

because if it is implied that `None` will always be `False`, and, unless you have a very strong reason to argue that why `None` should not be **falsy**, then why do I bother writing `if y is not None`? (*just evaluate it to False, skip it in the `or` comparator, and give me `default`, zoom zoom fast~*)

Some people go for succinct code, and they claim it readable. Some like clear, affirmative syntax, like the verbose one, and claim it readable. So I guess that's where you choose your camp :)

Comment: Err, can you explain why `0` has both TRUE and FALSE in the table? And any idea why 1 and -1 are in there twice?

Comment: @barny that was not a nice table, it was printed out. I just took it from the link. The second `0` should be `"0"` aka a string zero, as you can see from the article

Comment: Yes the code does show the difference. TBH you’d be better linking to something more clear/precise - at least the authoritative source is the Python documentation e.g. https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-or-test

Comment: I don’t mind the words you use, but I think you need a better reference and table that doesn’t confuse things.