# Evaluation order of boolean expressions in Python

Tags: python, boolean

I'm optimizing the performance of some Python code and once read that "obsolete" code in boolean expressions is not executed to save computing time. So I've created the following test program:

```
def fun(p):
    print p
    return False

if fun(1) and fun(2):
    print "This shouldn't print"
```

This code only prints one line.

```
1
```

So fun(2) is not called, because it won't change the result of the "and".

I'd like to learn more about this feature, but I don't know the right name/term to search for. What's this feature called?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting

Comment: It's called [Short Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: @avim not quite. [Lazy Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) is a related but distinct term. More specifically, Short-Circuit is a specific case of the general lazy evaluation. Many languages only support lazy evaluation of operands in the case of short circuit operators (C/++, Java, Python, etc.), vs. a language like Haskell that has all operands lazy-evaluated by default.