# In terms of efficiency/quickly rejecting things, does it matter if your if statements are on the same line?

Tags: python, performance, processing-efficiency

For example, say I want to find all numbers between 1 and 1000 that are divisible by 3 and 5. Would the code:

```
for i in range(1,1000):
    if i % 3==0 and i %5 == 0:
        blah
```

be less efficient than say

```
for i in range(1,1000):
    if i%3==0:
       if i%5==0:
           blah
```

Does the computer check for BOTH conditions? For example, if i=10. Would the computer in the first one compute BOTH i%3 and i%5, or would it compute i%3 and then break? In that case, it would be more efficient to put the easy to check/reject condition to the left, correct?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2580136/3001761

Comment: I learned a new phrase, short circuiting, thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python and many languages there is [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of the boolean expressions. This means the evaluation stops as soon as are we sure about the truth value of the boolean expression. In this regard, both your code fragments are equivalent.

You could however optimise by changing the order. For example it's better to use:

```
if i % 5 == 0 and i % 3 == 0
```

The reason is that it's rarer for a number to be a multiple of 5 and so this expression will fail earlier for most of the cases.

For example, if we check for the numbers from 1 to 150, the check `i % 5 == 0` will fail for 120 numbers. So we are going to perform 120 checks for `i % 5 == 0` and 30 checks for  `i % 5 == 0` and `i % 3 == 0`. This is a total of 180 checks. Similarly, for `if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0` we are going to perform `100 + 2 * 50 = 200` checks.

Comment: That's what I thought, it always better to quickly reject things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, it will return false as soon as one of the conditions is false. This is called short-circuiting. See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

Comment: Oh, that was simple. Is it the same in every language?

Comment: I'm not sure about "every" language but here is a list of some that [do support it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: @avid19 some languages require different syntax - for example in VB.NET the base `And` and `Or` don't short-circuit but `AndAlso` and `OrElse` do.

Answer (score -1):

Along side the other answers that explains the `short-circuiting`, The both do one job and there is no much difference between the performance.

See the following benchmark :

```
s1="""
for i in range(1,1000):
    if i % 3==0 and i %5 == 0:
        pass
"""
s2="""
for i in range(1,1000):
    if i%3==0:
       if i%5==0:
           pass

    """


print ' first: ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=1000)
print 'second : ',timeit(stmt=s2, number=1000)
```

Result :

```
 first:  0.0738339424133
second :  0.0790829658508
```

as you can see the difference is `0.006` and its because of an extra block loading in the second part.

Also you can use `dis` module for disassembling the python bytecode :

first loop using `and` :

```
 21           0 SETUP_LOOP              58 (to 61)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (1000)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 GET_ITER            
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                41 (to 60)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

 22          22 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             25 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             28 BINARY_MODULO       
             29 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             32 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             35 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16
             38 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             41 LOAD_CONST               5 (5)
             44 BINARY_MODULO       
             45 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             48 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             51 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

 23          54 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
             57 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   60 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   61 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             64 RETURN_VALUE
```

and for second :

```
26           0 SETUP_LOOP              61 (to 64)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (1000)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 GET_ITER            
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                44 (to 63)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

 27          22 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             25 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             28 BINARY_MODULO       
             29 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             32 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             35 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

 28          38 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             41 LOAD_CONST               5 (5)
             44 BINARY_MODULO       
             45 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             48 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             51 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       60

 29          54 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           60
             57 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   60 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   63 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   64 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             67 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: -1, the assembly for these two expressions is *identical*.  Any difference in timing is a result of the variance and unreliability of the test environment.

Comment: @NickBastin I think was showing that, they said "there is no(t) much difference between the performance".

Comment: @NickBastin As avid19 says i didn't say there is no any difference! check out the edit!