# Booleans with numbers in Python

Tags: python, boolean

I came across this implementation of gcd in Python:

```
def gcd(x,y): return y and gcd(y, x % y) or x
```

What I don't understand is how the boolean is working in the return? After trying some numbers in the interpreter I noticed that `and` always returns the number on the right, while `or` returns the number on the left. Why is this? Also, can you walk me step by step through a simple call of this function so I can understand what is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python support short-circuiting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Comment: This could be rewritten as `def gcd(x, y): return gcd(y, x % y) if y else x`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator.

Comment: One other thing to point out is that 'and' has greater precedence than 'or'  which is why when 'y and gcd(y, x % y)' is False, x is returned.  See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of how `and` and `or` operators evaluate in Python.

From [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

They do not return `True` or `False` , they return the last evaluated value , and that is why we can write things like -

```
s = s or "Some default value"
```

To default the value of `s` if its `None` or empty string or empty list, or 0.

---

Basically, `or` returns the first non false-like value ( where false-like values are 0, or None or Empty string/list/tuple, etc ) Or the last false-like value if all the values are false-like. Example -

```
In [1]: 0 or 10
Out[1]: 10

In [2]: 5 or 0 or 10
Out[2]: 5

In [7]: 0 or '' or [] or ()
Out[7]: ()
```

And, `and` returns the first false-like value, or the last true-like value , if all the values are true-like. Example -

```
In [3]: 0 and 10
Out[3]: 0

In [4]: 5 and 10
Out[4]: 10

In [6]: 5 and 0 and 10
Out[6]: 0
```

---

In your case, it works as -

1. if `y` is 0 it returns x (irrespective of the value of x) .
2. otherwise it computes `gcd(y, x%y)` if that is non-zero returns it. (Though it would never really be `0`)
3. if the result of `gcd(y, x%y)` is 0, then it returns `x` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar In this example, gcd(y, x%y) would never be zero thought right? since the only results that are ever really returned are either y if non-zero or x, which is always non-zero?

Comment: Correct it would never be 0 , I just put it there for the explanation of the boolean operators.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought, just checking. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is called "short circuiting."  Whenever Python knows what the result of a boolean expression is going to be, it stops evaluating.  This is an optimization, but it also makes for some handy idioms, like assigning default values.

```
def do_a_thing(maybelist=None):
    # this is done all the time when you want the default argument to be
    # a list, but you don't want to make the mistake of a mutable default argument
    maybelist = maybelist or []
```

The implementation example you gave is confusing to someone who doesn't know about [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for calculating gcd's, because it's not obvious how the heck it actually calculates the gcd.  I would say that that is an example of someone abusing short circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the only integer that defaults to False is zero.  Logical values perform short-circuiting, as one of the comments say.

With the statement:

```
a and b
```

If 'a' evaluates to False, then 'b' does not need to be evaluated, so the result of the expression is 'a', but if 'a' evaluates to True, then `b` still needs to be evaluated, so `b` will be the result of the expression unless `a` evaluates to False.

`or' works the other way around, which makes sense if you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

`and` and `or` are not strictly Boolean operators in Python. `x and y` and `x or y` will always evaluate to either `x` or `y`, depending on the "truthiness" of the value. False values are numerical zeros, empty strings, and empty containers; all other values are true. This means that

- `x and y == x` if `x` is false; `y` is not evaluated
- `x and y == y` if `x` is true
- `x or y == x` if `x` is true; `y` is not evaluated
- `x or y == y` if `x` is false

The only time either evaluates to an actual Boolean value is when the `x` or `y` value involved is an actual Boolean value.