# C# && in python

Tags: c#, python

Is there Python equivalent of `&&` operator in C#? 
Quick clarification, in C# `if x && y` if `x` is not true, then `y` is not even going to evaluated.

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting): Python's `and` supports short-circuiting

Comment: @John3136, thank you corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`and` in Python is the same as `&&` in other languages