# While loop check one condition before the other

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm new to programming, and I want to write some code like

```
while(condition_A and condition_B):  
    #Do something
```

But each time I run the while loop, I want to check condition A first, and if condition A works then check condition B. For example, condition A checks if condition B will get an array out of bounds error or something. And finally if both conditions are true stay in the while loop. How should I do this? I was thinking of something like

```
 def some_While_Loop:
      if condition_A == False:
          return
      while (condition_B):
         #Do something
         if condition_A == False:
               return
```

But then the while loop has to be the last thing a function does. Is there a nicer/better way?

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us which programming language you're doing this in as many languages do this out of the box with the right syntax.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me can you explain a bit...

Comment: The syntax looks like Python, in which case your first example is already correct but is then a duplicate of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting - this feature is called "short circuiting logical operators".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using python.
You actually had the answer yourself:

```
while(condition_A and condition_B):  
    #Do something
```