# How can I check if a variable exists in multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Here's an excerpt from my code!

```
division = ["Division","Divide","/","div"]
multiplication =["*","x","times","multiply","multiplication","multiple"]
subtraction = ["-",'minus','subtract','subtraction']
addition = ['+','plus','addition','add']
root = ['root','squareroot','square root']
square = ['square','squared','power 2']

choice = input('calculation type')
print(choice == (division or multiplication or subtraction or addition))
```

So far, it only gives "False".
How can I check if a variable exists in multiple lists?
I've tried to make lists inside of lists but I still get "False", Here's the code of that...

```
division = ["Division","Divide","/","div"]
multiplication = ["*","x","times","multiply","multiplication","multiple"]
subtraction = ["-",'minus','subtract','subtraction']
addition = ['+','plus','addition','add']
root = ['root','squareroot','square root']
square = ['square','squared','power 2']
basic_double = [division,multiplication,subtraction,addition]
basic_single = [root,square]
choice = input('calculation type')
print(choice == basic_double or basic_single)
```

Any help would be appreciated! :D thank you!!!

Comment: `any(choice in ls for ls in [division, multiplication, subtraction, addition])`

Comment: @L3viathan I hope its not too much, I'm really new xD, but can you please explain HAHAHHAHA SORRY :DD

Comment: I will explain in the answer.

Comment: I feel like there should be a list of common mess-up sources and the reasons why they are wrong. Lots of people seem to have trouble with the fact that `or` in python doesn't work like that.

Comment: @ElliotRoberts that would be really helpful for beginners 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test whether the `choice` is in `any` of the lists:

```
any(choice in ls for ls in [division, multiplication, subtraction, addition])
```

`any` returns True if at least one of the elements of the given iterable are truthy.

`choice in ls` tests whether choice is an element of the list.

`choice in ls for ls in [division, multiplication, subtraction, addition]` is a generator comprehension, meaning it's an iterator that returns the result of `choice in ls` for any possible `ls` in `[division, multiplication, subtraction, addition]`.

If *one* of those lists contains the `choice`, `any` will return True, False otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You may take the use of [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to check the choice in all the list as:

```
if choice in chain(division, multiplication, subtraction, addition):
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if choise is in any of the four lists you provided in your example:

```
if choice in division + multiplication + subtraction + addition:
   # do something when its in any of it.
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're comparing a String, choice, to a series of lists. This will never be True as you're comparing two different data types.

You should check against each list using the "in" keyword

```
if choice in division:
     #this returns true if the String set to choice is in the list of objects in division.
else if choice in multiplication:
.
.
.
```

This comparison will help you find the word in the list that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your code is doing the following comparison inside the print function:

```
choice == ["Division","Divide","/","div"] or ["*","x","times","multiply","multiplication","multiple"] or ["-",'minus','subtract','subtraction'] or ['+','plus','addition','add']
```

Because of [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2580136/102022), this reduces to:

```
choice == ["Division","Divide","/","div"]
```

Which always evaluates to `False` because `choice` is not a list.

I'd flatten the list containing `[division, multiplication, subtraction, addition]` and then test to see if `choice` is in that list.

```
flattened = [item for ls in [division, multiplication, subtraction, addition] for item in ls]

print(choice in flattened)
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/102022) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/102022) for more details on flattening a list of lists in python.