# OR in python3 assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm kinda new to python and this time I'm using it for AI in games programming which includes graphics.

I saw an example of code in the book which is

```
def __init__(self, m=None):
    if isinstance(m, Matrix33):
        m = list(m._m)
    self._m = m or [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]
```

how does python situate OR on the assignment of a variables without any condition?

Comment: It will check if `m` is empty list or `None` and if so set the list `[1.0, ...]` to `self._m`. Otherwise `self._m` will be set to `m`

Comment: @kuro, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python support short-circuiting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your expectation is that the boolean operator `or` returns `True` or `False`. But it doesn't. `or` returns the first of its operands to evaluate to `True`.

So:

`1 or 0` --> `1` (treated as `True` if you use it where a bool is expected)

`0 or 'B'` --> `'B'` (treated as `True` if you use it where a bool is expected)

The example you cite is an idiom that you will find in most languages that automatically cast non-boolean datatypes to booleans, a long tradition that goes back to PL/1. The idiom can lead you astray if you are expecting the first operand to contain either `None` or a valid value, and the valid value you get is actually zero.

You could also express it more explicitly as

```
self._m = m if m else [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]
```