# Processing of Booleans in Python

Tags: python, logical-operators

I have a question about a logical expression of the following sort:

```
for i in range (k): #k is large
    if (a==b and test(c)==b): #test() takes some time to calculate
         do something
```

Now I want to know, how the logical expression is processed. Are the two simple expressions calculated first and then combined via `and`? Or is `a==b` calculated, and in case it is `False`, `test(c)==b` neglected?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `and` short-circuits and the second expression is not evaluated if the first produced false.

Comment: Check out this Question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting

Answer (score 2):

The `a==b` will be calculated first, and if it's true then the second expression will be evaluated. This is known as 'short-circuiting', see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).