# Experimenting with tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I am complete noob in python. I was trying to figure out working with tuples. So, I did the following and I do not understand the result.

```
n=12        
m = (0,1,2)

print n and m   
# Result  (0, 1, 2)

print n or m  
# Result 12
```

This might have been asked before but I couldn't find any related.

Comment: The boolean operations short-circuit in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting. In other words if the first operand is truthy, then `or` has no need to evaluate the second operand. Similarly if it is falsy then `and` has no need to evaluate the second.

Comment: This is documented in case you want to read what the official documentation says about it: ["Expressions: Boolean operations"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)