# No TypeError comparing int with None in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype, short-circuiting

I understand that comparing int and None types is not valid in Python3 (3.6.1) as I see here:

```
>>> largest = None
>>> number = 5
>>> number > largest
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of int and NoneType
```

But inside this script it doesn't give a TypeError.

```
largest = None
for number in [5, 20, 11]:
    if largest is None or number > largest:
        largest = number
```

When I run this script with python3 it runs without a TypeError. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python support short-circuiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Comment: Your script isn't the same logic. That's why you have no errors. By the way `max([5, 20, 11])` works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're witnessing `short circuiting`.

```
if largest is None or number > largest:
        (1)        or      (2)
```

When condition `(1)` is evaluated to be true, condition `(2)` is *not* executed. In the first iteration, `largest is None` is `True`, so the *whole expression* is true.

---

As an illustrative example, consider this little snippet.

```
test = 1
if test or not print('Nope!'):
     pass

# Nothing printed
```

Now, repeat with `test=None`:

```
test = None
if test or not print('Nope!'):
     pass

Nope!
```

Comment: thanks. you got me at...condition 2 is not executed in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine your code carefully, you'll notice that you initialize largest to `None`, then conditionally ask if it is `None`, thus the if statement evaluates as `True`.