# object of type 'NoneType' has no len() :

Tags: python, django, nonetype

```
def send_ivr_calls(sp_orders, base_url, api_key, extra_data):
    for contact in sp_orders:
        if len(contact) == 10:
            contact = '0'+contact
```

---

```
File "views.py", line 43, in calls if len(contact) == 10:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

How can I check whether the `sp_orders` list does not contain any `None`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def send_ivr_calls(sp_orders, base_url, api_key, extra_data):
    for contact in sp_orders:
        if contact and len(contact) == 10:
                contact = '0'+contact
```

This is ensures contact is not None before you try to get its length. Credit to @Moses Koledoye for pointing out short-circuiting.

Comment: Why not use one *if* clause and shortcircuit with `and`. Although the parser is very likely to fix it so it might not be much of a problem.

Comment: `if contact and len(contact) == 10` won't break. If contact is *falsy*, it's length will never be checked.

Comment: @Kyle Higginson, [good thread about short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 1):

```
if contact is not None and len(contact) == 10:
    contact = '0'+contact
```