# Why does python ignore the first part of a condition?

Tags: python, logical-operators

Suppose I have the following code:

```
target = 'abc1234y'
if ('x' and 'y') in target:
    print('x and y are in target')
```

Why is `if ('x' and 'y') in target` true?

Why doesn't this code produce error?

Why do braces have no effect?

This does not seem logical, since if `('x' and 'y') = true` then `('y' and 'x')` should also be true, however, this is no the case.

At the same time expression `if ('y' and 'x') in target` is `false`

Comment: What do you mean *Why do braces have no effect?*. They **do**. The difference is between `('x' and 'y') in target` and `'x' and ('y' in target)`. They're very different!

Comment: Can you please explain in words what you're trying to compare? Because it is not "x and y are in the target string"

Comment: Braces have no effect means I expect ('x' and 'y') mean 'x' and 'y' not x and 'y in somewhere'

Comment: @0rt Unfortunately that's not how programming works, you'll need to say `'x' in target and 'y' in target` or something similar to the same effect

Comment: @NickA, does it omit them?

Comment: @0rt Does it omit what?

Comment: @NickA, braces around expression ('x' and 'y')

Comment: @0rt No, read the first comment I posted and go ***thoroughly*** read up on operator precedence, and also probably [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things to consider here:

## How `and` works with strings

`'x' and 'y'` is not `True`.

`'x' and 'y'` is `'y'`, which might seem confusing but it makes sense when looking at how `and` and `or` work in general:

- `a and b` returns `b` if a is `True`, else returns `a`.
- `a or b` returns `a` if a is `True`, else returns `b`.

Thus:

- `'x' and 'y'` is `'y'`
- `'x' or 'y'` is `'x'`

## What the parentheses do

The brackets do have an effect in your if statement. `in` has a higher precedence than `and` meaning that if you write

```
if 'x' and 'y' in target:
```

it implicitly means the same as

```
if 'x' and ('y' in target):
```

which will only check if y is in the target string. So, using

```
if ('x' and 'y') in target:
```

will have an effect. You can see the whole table of operator precedences in [the Python docs about Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

## Solution

To achieve what you are wanting to do, @Prem and @Olga have already given two good solutions:

```
if 'y' in target and 'x' in target:
```

or

```
if all(c in target for c in ['x','y']):
```

Comment: I agree the down votes are just random. The answers look correct. Not sure what is wrong with the answers.

Comment: You have my upvote for the nice explanation on behaviour

Comment: so, in python and does not act like &?

Comment: @0rt `and` and `&` are quite different things in python. `and` is logical, `&` is bitwise

Comment: Could you explain why do braces have no effect on the expression?

Comment: @0rt They do have an effect!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing how `AND` operator works.

```
'x' and 'y'
Out[1]: 'y'
```

and

```
'y' and 'x'
Out[1]: 'x'
```

So in your first case, you do check if `y` is present. In reverse, you check if `x` is present in string.

Comment: why does it ignore the braces then?

Comment: @0rt it doesn't ignore braces, `('x' and 'y')` is `'y'` so all your statement is doing is `'y' in target`

Comment: The braces says, the condition should be evaluated first.

Comment: maybe you want to test "if 'x' in target and 'y' in target".

Comment: I'd like to understand the 'x' and 'y' behaviour. Is it a known and wanted behaviour or just some side effect to consider ?

Comment: @IMCoins it's well defined behaviour, it's called [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is checking for just 'y' in target.
You need something like this:

```
target = 'abc1234y'
if 'y' in target and 'x' in target:
    print('x and y are in target')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `all` instead 

`if all(c in target for c in ['x','y']):...`

Comment: this is not what I was asking for