# DJango form.is_valid() function only clean the first form in an if statement

Tags: python, django, django-views

I notice that `forms.is_valid` only clean form for the first form in an if statement.

Example code :

```
if not user_detail_form.is_valid() and not user_location_form.is_valid():
       return redirect('account:profile')
```

Accessing cleaned data of user_detail_form works but when accessing cleaned data of user_location_form, it throws an error stating that cleaned_data does not exists.

My question is

What causes this? and is there a workaround for this?

Comment: both ```not user_detail_form.is_valid()``` and ```not user_location_form.is_valid()``` returns false. why did it skipped?

Comment: I don't think there is a way for my forms to be invalid because it's rendered by the template engine it self.

Comment: It didn't redirect either, if one of the conditions is true it would have redirected

Comment: I thought the code is like, "If both conditions is false redirect", not "if one condition is false, skipped it"

Comment: hmmm, thanks, this is a sign I need to learn more.

Comment: I always thought that the ```if and``` will execute a code if both is the same. apparently, it needs both to be true.

Comment: I've added some updates to my answer, including a link to a related question. Start there to study this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate your forms before the if-statement, to avoid missing evaluation due to `and` short-circuiting:

```
detailvalid = user_detail_form.is_valid()
locationvalid = user_location_form.is_valid()
if not detailvalid and not locationvalid:
   return redirect('account:profile')
```

---

More generally, in

```
if 1 == 2 and 3 == 3:
```

the second part is never evaluated, because the first part fails.

With `or`, it's the other way around:

```
if 1 == 1 or 2 == 3:
```

now, the first part succeeds, and the second part is (again) never evaluated.

More importantly, in both cases, if that second part involves a function call (e.g. `is_valid()`), *that function is never called*.

More info at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting), in particular [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14892812/707650).