# are compounded equality tests short circuited in python?

Tags: python

Does python short circuit a boolean like `a==b==c`, i.e., if `a==b` is false, then the second equality isn't evaluated? Is the compound equality just syntactic sugar for `a==b and b==c`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python support short-circuiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Comment: @Ambrosia only if the answer to my second question about syntactic sugar is "yes"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y` and `y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

This applies to any chained comparison, regardless of the chosen comparison operators.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily; for example, `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).