# Comparing integers to None Types

Tags: python, python-3.x

This a problem in my textbook, where you create a program that makes a histogram of the emails in the text file (which they are always the second word).

```
handle = open("mbox-short.txt")

senders = {}
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From'):
        emails = line.split()
        if len(emails) < 3: continue
        email = emails[1]
        senders[email] = senders.get(email , 0) + 1

bigsender = None 
bigcount = None
for sender,times in senders.items():
    if bigcount < times:
        bigcount = times
        bigsender = sender    

print(bigsender, bigcount)
```

But when I run it produces an error which says:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Yet when I change the last condition to:

```
if bigcount is None or bigcount < times:
```

Aren't we still comparing bigcount to times, I don't get what did change?

This is text file: https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt

Comment: If `bigcount` is `None`, then the condition `bigcount is None or bigcount < times` evaluates to true without checking `bigcount < times`. See [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: you could just initiate `bigcount = 0` (or `float('-inf')` if you must)

Comment: See [Does Python support short-circuiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Comment: @Chris_Rands then I can use any negative number, right? 
since the count is always positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `if bigcount is None or bigcount < times` you have two separate conditions: `bigcount is None` and `bigcount < times`. If we go in order, `bigcount is None` is evaluated as `true`. Because there is no possible value that `bigcount < times` can take that can make this entire line false (because `true or some_boolean` is always true for any possible value of `some_boolean`), the evaluation short circuits and **doesn't** evaluate the second statement, so never gets a chance to produce the type error.

In other words, `bigcount < times` produces an error, because you can't compare `bigcount` and `times`, but in your second example that bit of code is never evaluated.

Comment: I think you should clarify your answer, I could not really understand what you meant when I first read it