# How to check if any of array values' lengths is equal to 1

Tags: python

I want to check if any length of value in array is equal to 1. I have an array

```
SLR = [4, 4000, 4010]
```

I want to check if any of these values' length: is equal to 1. In this case it's true because there's 4.

I tried to do this that way but of course it failed:

```
SLR = [4, 4000, 4010]

if(any(len(SLR)) == 1):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

Comment: It looks like SLR contains integers, so instead of `len()` maybe something like `any(n < 10 for n in SLR)`

Comment: Numbers don't have lengths; string representations of a number (in a given base) do.

Comment: The question does not make sense as asked, because none of the values in question have a length at all, so it is not possible to check whether their lengths are equal to 1. If the question is simply about how to make `any` work, please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast the `int` to `str` and check `len()`, i.e.:

```
SLR = [4, 4000, 4010]
if [x for x in SLR if len(str(x)) == 1]:
    print("yes")
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/2b31a3ea3d)

---

Or taking advantage of [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14892812/797495) as [@kaya3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299000/kaya3) suggested:

```
if any(len(str(x)) == 1 for x in SLR):
    print("yes")
```

To use with negative numbers:

```
SLR = [-9, 22, 4000, 4010]
if any(-10 < n < 10 for n in SLR):
    print("yes")
```

Comment: `any(len(str(x)) == 1 for x in SLR)` has the advantage of short-circuiting, and not building an unnecessary list.

Comment: A beautiful way of doing it, @kaya3. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, you could filter the list and return a length greater than 1 for the final subset:

```py
return len(list(filter(lambda x: len(str(x)) == 1, SLR))) >= 1
```