# result in tuple for conditional expression using Python

Tags: python, tuples, conditional-statements

I'm trying see how I can use a tuple in conditional statement like this:

```
(False_condition, True_Condition)[conditional expression]
```

Assign example values:

```
x, y = 4, 7
```

Conditional:

```
("x is greater than y", "x is less than y") [x < y]
```

Output:

```
'x is less than y'
```

Problem: What if x == y?

Assign value:

```
x,y = 5,5
```

Conditional:

```
("x is greater than y", "x is less than y", "x is equal to y") [x < y]
```

Output:

```
"x is greater than y"
```

Question: In this method, can you NOT have a third option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to what you want with this:

```py
print(( "x is less than y", "x is equal to y", "x is greater than y")[ [x<y,x==y,x>y].index(True)])
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works? What's happening?

Comment: I put all three conditions in a list. Only one of them will be true and the index method reports the index of that one, which is then used to pick the text string from the tuple of the descriptions.

Comment: this is actually the best solution. You can list any number of conditions this way, they all will be in the order, and it looks intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you want

```py
("x is greater than y", "x is less than y", "x is equal to y")[(x < y) or (x==y)*2]
```

Looks weird, ha?

That's because in the square brackets after a tuple python expects a number.
And the thing is, conditional `false` evaluates to `0` and conditional `true` evaluates to `1` with implicit *type coercion*.

So to make this work you would have to figure out a oneliner with conditionals, that will evaluate as follows:

- `0` if `x > y`
- `1` if `x < y`
- `2` if `x == y`

We can utilize a so-called **short-circuiting** properties (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14892812).

0. this guy `x < y` makes for the first 2 cases. We can separate it out with parenthesis: `(x < y)`.
1. with `(x < y) or whatever`, it will produce `true` (`1`) with the first statement if `x < y` and stop there, but if `x < y` happens to be `false` (`0`), then the `or` statement will proceed on evaluating the statement on the right, and return `whatever`, whatever it will be.
2. so with `(x < y) or (x==y)*2`, if `x < y` then it will return `true` (`1`) right away, but if not: it will return `(x==y)*2`, which is either `false` (`0`) or `true` (`1`) multiplied by `2`, so either `0` or `2`.

Thus we have:

- `0`, if both `x < y` and `x == y` are false (i.e. `x > y`)
- `1`, if `x < y` returns `true` (`1`)
- `2`, if `x < y` is `false`, and `x==y` is `true` (`1`)

In fact, if we utilize **short-circuiting** properties of `and` statement, `(x==y)*2` may be substituted to `(x==y) and 2`, yielding the same results, but running with a bit less CPU time. This approach may be used to refactor numbers of nested `if` statements that is intended to run a big number of times (usually > 1'000'000 times), and is called **branchless programming**.

P.S. You may want not to put everything in one line.

Comment: This is a thorough explanation that helps me understand some fundamental concepts. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambdas they are more efficient because in lambda   only one expression will be evaluated unlike in tuple and Dictionary :

`(lambda x,y:"x:{} is greater than y:{}".format(x,y), lambda x,y: "x:{} is less than y:{}".format(x,y) if x<y else "x:{} equal to y:{}".format(x,y))[x<=y](x,y)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I usually use:

```
>>> for x, y in (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1):
        print('=<>'[(x < y) - (x > y)])

<
=
>
```

Although kukuster is right, `or` is faster. I might switch.

```
>>> for x, y in (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1):
        print('=<>'[(x < y) or -(x > y)])

<
=
>
```