# Why is my and in a if statement not working?

Tags: python

if guess in word:

```
    if guess == word[0] and 1 >= len(word):
        print("Your guess is correct. The letter of the word you guess has been revealed. ")
        right[0] = word[0]
        print(' '.join(right))
        score +=1
    if guess == word[1] and 2 >= len(word):
        print("Your guess is correct. The letter of the word you guess has been revealed. ")
        right[1] = word[1]
        print(' '.join(right))
        score +=1
        print(score)
    if guess == word[2] and 3 >= len(word):
        print("Your guess is correct. The letter of the word you guess has been revealed. ")
        right[2] = word[2]
        print(' '.join(right))
        score +=1
        print(score)
    if guess == word[3] and 4 >= len(word):
        print("Your guess is correct. The letter of the word you guess has been revealed. ")
        right[3] = word[3]
        print(' '.join(right))
        score +=1
        print(score)
    if guess == word[4] and 5 >= len(word):
        print("Your guess is correct. The letter of the word you guess has been revealed. ")
        right[4] = word[4]
        print(' '.join(right))
        score +=1
        print(score)
```

The error is:
if guess == word[1] and 2 >= len(word):
IndexError: string index out of range

I think the problem is with the and in the if statement but I dont know.

Comment: You should first check the length and then access the element.

Comment: Do you mean to write `if len(word) > 1 and word[1]==guess` ? Because what you have is not that at all. Not only are you checking conditions in the wrong order; you're checking the wrong conditions.

Comment: @User6510 Why did you edited your code back to an incorrect formatting?

Comment: Sorry if my code is confusing. I'm new to python and trying to learn. The project I am going for is hangman

Comment: This behavior is called short-circuiting. This question has more info: [Does Python support short-circuiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first check the length and then access the element. Additionally the size check is wrong. Change

```
if guess == word[1] and 2 >= len(word):
```

to

```
if len(word) >= 2 and guess == word[1]:
```

Comment: `2 >= len(word)` does not guard against the IndexError.

Comment: `len(word) >= 2` or `2 <= len(word)` would be correct. The former seems more natural than the latter.

Comment: @khelwood You are right. I didn't see it and I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you with your change my code now works.