# Python3 check if string is a specific type of list expression(without eval)

Tags: python

A string, for example, `string = "[["3", "4"], ["2", "5"]]"`.

Now I need to check if it is a list expression, with all elements being lists(e.g. `["3","4"]`) that contains two string in it.

Is there any simple ways to check that? (I'd prefer not using `eval()` for safety reason)

Comment: `isinstance(json.loads(string), list)`.Or `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Great! That answers my question. May you make a answer so I can accept it?

Comment: this is very clever solution, but be aware that your string might not always be json-like

Comment: Well, this answer is from here :[How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list).You could get more details about that.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, for the `ast.literal_eval()` part; And no, for checking each element is a list with 2 string elements in it- but I think it's pretty easy after I know  how to safely convert the string to list.

Comment: Well, use `len` and something like `all(isinstance(s, str) for s in sublist)`... Anyway your question is too broad. If you are able to convert to a list, ask a specific question about how to check if it has two lists of two strings

Comment: @Tomerikoo I will use `all` and list conprehension for that undoubtedly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to  make it a list.

Docs for [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, **lists**, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.

Code for [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

l = ast.literal_eval('[["3", "4"], ["2", "5"]]')
```

Or you could also use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) (usually used for loading JSON):

Docs for [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

> Deserialize s (a str, bytes or bytearray instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

Code for [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

l = json.loads('[["3", "4"], ["2", "5"]]')
```

---

To check if each element is a list you can use:

```
def checkEachElementIsList(l):
    for elem in l: 
        if type(elem) != list:
            return False
    return True
```

Or you could use:

```
def checkEachElementIsList(l):
    return all(type(elem) is list for elem in l)
```

Comment: Well you basically implemented the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function. Your `checkEachElementIsList` function is equivalent to `all(type(elem) is list for elem in l)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes but `checkEachElementIsList(l)` is sometimes slightly faster than `all(type(elem) is list for elem in l)` since it might not need to go through all them elements in the list

Comment: `all` is the same.

Comment: `all` doesn't as well... It's called [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA But it will need to go through all the element in the list

Comment: Check the docs... The implementation is exactly the same as your function

Comment: by the way, that `break` in the function is uneccessary since `return` already stops the function directly.

Comment: @Acc-lab Now removed `break`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Fixed that as well now

Answer (score 0):

> Now I need to check if it is a list expression, with all elements being lists(e.g. ["3","4"]) that contains two string in it.

```
import ast

string = "[['3', '4'], ['2', '5']]"

data = ast.literal_eval(string)
if isinstance(data, list):
    print('we have a list')
    for entry in data:
        if isinstance(entry,list):
            print('we have inner list')
            if len(entry) == 2:
                print('Inner list contains 2 items')
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but you forgot to check if the `entry`'s elements are strings.

Comment: I can do that part