# Does python stop verification on first wrong condition in "if and" or does it check it all before deciding?

Tags: python, if-statement, optimization

I have multiple expensive condition to make and I am wondering if this:

```
if False and False and True and False:
    print("you will never see this")
```

is longer than this in time computing:

```
if False:
    if False:
        if True:
            if False:
                print("you will never see this")
```

Will python stop the first time it see a wrong condition or will it compute every verification before deciding ?

Comment: Python evaluates that *lazily*, although given that you have hard-coded conditions it all has to be *parsed* anyway. But e.g. `foo() and bar()` won't call bar if foo returns false-y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter, because Python supports short-circuit evaluation:

[Does Python support short-circuiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, sorry for the duplicate, I didn't find the rights keywords. (but I think these keywords can still be useful).
So the answer is "yes Python stop at the first wrong condition".