# Sort words which can include characters like "ç","ş" without using any module

Tags: python

I tried to modify bubble sort algorithm but it does not work correctly, it sorts the list arr2 like ['a', 'abc', 'bba', 'bbbcc', 'ccaakl', 'ccb', 'çalışkan çocuk ', 'çimen', 'mmmmmm', 'zmm', 'ğayrimenkul', 'şimşek', 'şş'] as you can see , letters "ğ","z","ş" are wrong sorted. I cannot find the mistake.

Here is the dict and arr:

```
arr2=["çalışkan çocuk ","a","şş","bbbcc","ccaakl","zmm","mmmmmm","abc","bba","ccb","şimşek","çimen","ğayrimenkul"]

letters_dict ={" ":30,"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2, "ç": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6, "g": 7, "ğ": 8, "h": 9, "ı": 10, "i": 11,"j": 12, "k": 13,
               "l": 14, "m": 15, "n": 16, "o": 17, "ö": 18, "p": 19, "r": 20, "s": 21, "ş": 22,"t": 23, "u": 24, "ü": 25, "v": 26, "y":27,"z":28}
```

And the sorting function:

```
def bubbleSort(arr,letters_dict):
   n = len(arr)

   for i in range(n - 1):
      for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
         if (("ç" or "ğ" or "ö" or "ş" or "ü") in arr[j]) or (("ç" or "ğ" or "ö" or "ş" or "ü") in arr[j+1]):
            for x in range(len(min(arr[j],arr[j+1]))):
               if letters_dict[arr[j][x]] > letters_dict[arr[j+1][x]]:
                  arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
                  break
               elif letters_dict[arr[j][x]] < letters_dict[arr[j+1][x]]:
                  break
         else:
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
               arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
   return arr
```

Comment: "it does not work correctly": Please provide details.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: There is a first serious misconception in your code: `"ç" or "ğ" or "ö" or "ş" or "ü"` actually returns `"ç"`. I mean, try `("ç" or "ğ" or "ö" or "ş" or "ü") == "ç"`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting) to go further.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true

Comment: You cannot just sort these by their Unicode codepoint. The rules on how to sort special characters even differ from language to language. You can access this through the locale module in python.