# Can I store keywords as values to variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

given a string "A & B & C"  with values of A,B abd C = 0,0,1 respectively, it would be solved as `0 & 0 & 1` to give a result of `0`.

I am writing a program where I want to check for & and | for logic operation to return the result.
in this case, I wish to have something like this `logic = and`. But unfortunately `and` is a python reserved keyword and it will throw the error below;

```
File "<ipython-input-248-9d5aa5c6e082>", line 1
    logic = and
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Assuming you could do this, how do you expect it to work any different than using `and` directly? In other words, you'd just be storing a pointer to an operator, and still need to use the actual operator

Comment: Can you clarify what *behaviour* you expect? What should be contained inside ``logic``? How would one use it? The boolean operators ``and``/``or`` cannot be expressed by function calls, so "storing" them makes little sense – you cannot use them.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the use case? For example, can you give an example of a function that you'd like to be able to write if you knew the answer to this question?

Comment: I think they are looking to be able to parse `True logic False` where `logic` might be a variable assigned either  `and` or `or`.  Is that correct @dismas?

Comment: Are you aware that Python has a ``&`` operator? This one can be stored in a variable, via ``operator.__add__``.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a keyword in this way. You might think that you could use the built-in module [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) to achieve your goal. This module contains functions that have the same behaviour as the built-in operators, and you can store a reference to one of those functions.

However, logical `and` and `or` are missing from this module (`and_` and `or_` are bitwise). This is probably because these operators exhibit ["short-circuit" behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting), which can't be emulated in a function call.

If it's okay for you not to have short-circuiting, it's trivial to implement these functions yourself:

```py
>>> and_ = lambda a, b: a and b
>>> logic = and_
>>> logic(True, False)
False
>>> logic(True, True)
True
```

Comment: ``operator.and_`` is the bitwise ``&`` not the logical ``and``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Well spotted! Do you know where logical `and` resides? The module contains logical `not_`, but I can't find the other logical operators...

Comment: There is no logical ``and`` ``operator``. The ``and`` operator cannot be accurately expressed as a function – that would destroy its short-circuit behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between functions and operators in python is that functions are objects and operators are not. What this means is that `and` is not a "thing" in python that you can pass around the way you could pass around a value or a function or an object or a class.

You could pass around "the idea of `and`", by encapsulating it in a function:

```
and_logic = lambda x, y: a and b
```

This means that you'd now have a function which, for any `a` and `b` returns the logical result of `a and b`. This function could now be passed around in potentially useful or interesting ways.

But since you don't give a lot of information about what you want to do in your question, it's hard to be more specific about what you can do with this idea.

EDIT: Just after I submitted this, I learned something from @Thomas' post. Apparently, the work of creating the lambda has been done for you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. You can do almost fancy things by using Python.

```
>>> import operator
>>> op = operator.or_
>>> print(op(1, 2))
3
```