# Python - print and return in for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, return, list-comprehension

I've just started learning Python. I saw an interesting code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting) that the author used to explain short-circuiting. The code is as follows:

```
>>> def fun(i):
...     print "executed"
...     return i
...
```

I tried to call fun(1). The output is the following and it makes perfect sense to me.

```
>>> fun(1)
executed
1
```

Then I tried `[fun(i) for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]]`, and the output looked like this:

```
>>> [fun(i) for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]]
executed
executed
executed
executed
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
executed
0
executed
1
executed
2
executed
3
```

Can anyone tell me what I got wrong? Thank you!

Comment: `[0, 1, 2, 3]` is the result of the list comprehension `[.. for .. in ..]`, which is output when that has completed. In the process of creating that list, a bunch of `print` statements were executed first.

Comment: FWIW, none of this has anything to do with *short circuiting*.

Comment: You can learn more about this topic from [www.certswarrior.com/exam/c2010-024/](http://www.certswarrior.com/exam/c2010-024/) and [www.certswarrior.com/exam/c2010-024/](http://www.certswarrior.com/exam/c2010-024/) course material.

Comment: Short-circuiting is using boolean results to avoid further execution (no need to execute more on a `or` call if you already have a True result). I don't know what you expected, but I guess you missed a call to `any` somewhere. I advise to read back the explanation on the other question :)

Comment: FWIW, you shouldn't learn *Python 2* in this day and age, it's been dead for a decade. Learn Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing

```
l = [fun(i) for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

This will output

> executed
> executed
> executed
> executed

Then just execute `l`, this will display the value of `l`, that is to say: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

So when you are executing

```
>>> [fun(i) for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

This calls fun(0), fun(1), and so on, and displays `executed`, then it displays the computed value: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> def fun(i):
...     print "executed"
...     return i
...
```

This is not example of short-circuiting. This is *function with side effect* - it does write to standard output, which is observable effect besides returning a value.

```
[fun(i) for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

This is `list` comprehension. Generally speaking you should have good reason to use function with side effect in such place, [PEP 202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) explains motivation for `list` comprehension as follows:

> List comprehensions provide a more concise way to create lists in
> situations where `map()` and `filter()` and/or nested loops would
> currently be used.

Someone reading your code therefore will probably assume it has to *just* create list, *without* printing elements during this action.

Answer (score 1):

Square brakets in this context form a new list, which each element is function fun of according element in [0, 1, 2, 3]. It is called list
[list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). "executed" is printed because during formation of new list function fun is called(for each element in [0, 1, 2, 3]). numbers 0,1,2 and 3 are not printed, because return value of fun is not printed, but put in the new list.
To see the new list:

```
print("new list:",[fun(i) for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```