# How can I remove the multiple returns from my code without ruining the output or having errors?

Tags: python

How can I remove the multiple returns from my code without ruining the output or having errors?

My code has multiple returns and I want it to have a single return but whenever I try to change it into one return it ruins my code and it doesn't escalate the way I want it.

**My Code:**

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Recursively determines if s is a palindrome. Ignores non-letters and case.
    Use: palindrome = is_palindrome(s)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        s - a string (str)
    Returns:
        palindrome - True if s is a palindrome, False otherwise (boolean)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        if not s[0].isalpha():
            return is_palindrome(s[1:])
        elif not s[-1].isalpha():
            return is_palindrome(s[:-1])
        if s[0].lower() != s[len(s) - 1].lower():
            return False
        else:
            return is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

Comment: Why do you want to have a single return? This is only making the code more complicated.

Comment: The argument for a single return statement makes for sense for function with nested conditions or loops which can hide the return; but in those cases you should probably refactor the code to reduce the cognitive complexity anyway. For such a simple/short function you should leave your code as it is and spend time on more important things.

Answer (score 2):

If we want "one point of exit" (return) we can save the result into a variable and return it at the end:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Recursively determines if s is a palindrome. Ignores non-letters and case.
    Use: palindrome = is_palindrome(s)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        s - a string (str)
    Returns:
        palindrome - True if s is a palindrome, False otherwise (boolean)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    if len(s) <= 1:
        res = True
    else:
        if not s[0].isalpha():
            res = is_palindrome(s[1:])
        elif not s[-1].isalpha():
            res = is_palindrome(s[:-1])
        elif s[0].lower() != s[len(s) - 1].lower():
            res = False
        else:
            res = is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
    return res
```

Note that the second `if` was modified to `elif` - this will not change the execution flow!

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a variable in all your conditional statements, then return that. You also need to change your second `if` to an `elif` to not execute if the previous statement did execute:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Recursively determines if s is a palindrome. Ignores non-letters and case.
    Use: palindrome = is_palindrome(s)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        s - a string (str)
    Returns:
        palindrome - True if s is a palindrome, False otherwise (boolean)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    if len(s) <= 1:
        out = True
    else:
        if not s[0].isalpha():
            out = is_palindrome(s[1:])
        elif not s[-1].isalpha():
            out = is_palindrome(s[:-1])
        elif s[0].lower() != s[len(s) - 1].lower():
            out = False
        else:
            out = is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your logic to a single long condition, which (though multi-line) is in some ways more readable, making the logic very clear:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return (len(s) <= 1
            or (not s[0].isalpha() and is_palindrome(s[1:])) 
            or (not s[-1].isalpha() and is_palindrome(s[:-1]))
            or (s[0].lower() == s[-1].lower() and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])))
```

This is just as efficient as your original code due to [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting) - conditions are only evaluated if and when they need to be evaluated.

If you strip the string of non-alphabetic characters first, then the recursive part can be made very simple:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    """ Determines if string s is a palindrome, ignoring non-alphabetic characters
        and ignoring case """
    return is_palindrome_general([c for c in s.lower() if c.isalpha()])

def is_palindrome_general(s):
    """ Determines if sequence s is a palindrome, treating all types of
        item the same """
    return len(s) <= 1 or (s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome_general(s[1:-1]))
```

(I split this into 2 functions just to avoid unnecessary repetition of the part that strips out the non-alphabetic characters.)