# Boolean in python

Tags: python

```
a=True and 1/0
print(a)
```

The output for the above code fragment shows an error.

While the output for the below code fragment :

```
a=False and 1/0
print(a)
```

Is False

Why is that so? From the layman point of view, since 1/0 is undefined, error should be displayed in each case.

Similarly if I take a = True or 1/0, output is true while an error for False or 1/0

I tried different versions of this:

```
a=1/0 or False
print(a)
```

or

```
a=1/0 or True
print(a)
```

Both of which display an error (division by zero)

I realized that it has something to do with the order I take them in and the boolean operators I use.

In any case, why am I getting an output and in some cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python support short-circuiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Comment: If you search "Python short circuting" on a search engine you can a more in depth on look on this subject.

Comment: @MaiconMauricio thank you, yes I went through a few articles on short circuiting

Answer (score 2):

Both `and` and `or` are [short circuited](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and) i.e. if the first input is respectively false or true, the rest of the inputs are not evaluated at all. That is why both `False and 1/0` as well as `True or 1/0` can return results, while other variations do not.

Answer (score 2):

Python exhibits [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) semantics for `and` and `or` expressions. What that means is that, if the result of the entire expression can be determined from the left-hand-side, then the right-hand-side needn't be evaluated.

```
False and a
```

Here, we first evaluate the expression `False` (which is a literal and equal to the Python value `False`). Now, `and` is only true if *both* sides are true, and we've already found one side which is false. So no matter what `a` evaluates to, the result is `False`. Hence, we don't evaluate the right-hand-side because it's unnecessary.

Likewise,

```
True or a
```

Since `True` is truthy and `or` only requires one of its arguments to be truthy, whatever `a` evaluates to, the result is `True`.

This is commonly used to do several veins of error checking in one line. Python doesn't have a [null-safe access operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator), so we can do the next best thing.

```
if person is not None and person.salary is not None:
    ...
```

Without short-circuit evaluation, the `person.salary is not None` would evaluate, even in the case where `person` is actually `None`, which is an error. We'd have to write the more verbose

```
if person is not None:
    if person.salary is not None:
        ...
```

which does nothing for readability.

Likewise, we can use `or` to short circuit error conditions.

```
if person is None or person.salary is None:
    raise(MyCustomException("This person doesn't have a job"))
```

Again, if `person` happens to be `None`, we don't want `person.salary` to evaluate at all, or we'll get an `AttributeError` rather than our nice, informative custom exception. Without short-circuiting, we'd have to resort to the *much* uglier

```
if person is None:
    raise(MyCustomException("This person doesn't have a job"))
if person.salary is None:
    raise(MyCustomException("This person doesn't have a job"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`and` operator stops when a `False` is encountered to save resources.

Here:

```
a=False and 1/0
```

Division is never computed.

The same you can check with `or` operator: it stops when `True` is validated:

```
a=True or 1/0
```

Will give `True`.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `False`, It is not necessary to check more after `and` - it is due to the optimization, so `1/0` is never executed.
On the other hand: `a=1/0 and False` will not work as `1/0` is evaluated first.