# which part of my code has made this specific line printed out?

Tags: python-3.x, function, printing

I started learning python and this is my first-ever question on stackoverflow.
Question is:
Why is *Function return false* printed when running the code?
Which part of my code has it printed out?

```py
def return_false():
    print("Function return false")
    return False
    
def return_true():
    print("Function return true")
    return True

print("test 2")

if return_false() and return_true():
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

```
test 2
Function return false  # I don't understand what makes this popped up.
False
```

Comment: `print("Function return false")` in line 2

Comment: You call both functions from your `if` statement. Since `return_false` returns `False` the `and` operator [short-circuits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting) and the second function (`return_true`) is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,the question needs some editing but as the edit queue is full i can't do the same so i'll answer your question instead.

Your code goes like:

```py
    def return_false():
        print('Function return false')
        return False
 
    def return_true():
        print('true')
        return True

    print('test 2')
    if return_false() and return_true():    # the problem is here
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

and the output you were expecting must be:

```
    test 2
    False
```

whereas the actual output is:

```
    test 2
    Function return false
    False
```

The problem is with the if statement (and mainly with the functions). So, your `print('test 2')` is responsible for the output `test 2` but as you write `if return_false() and return_true():` python calls the functions in order to get the return values. It first calls `return_false()` which not only returns `False` but also has a `print('Function return false')` statement enclosed in it so it is executed too and it is responsible for the extra `Function return false` output in your code.

Finally, heading next the if statement gets the `and` operator, but as the value for the logical comparision is `False` it doesn't have to check the second value cause no matter what the second value is the expression will always evaluate to `False` (as `True and False` or `False and False` will both result in `False`).Therefore, the code under the `if` block doesn't get executed and the program reaches the `else` statement and execcutes the `print('False')` statement, which is responsible for `False` as the last output.

To fix this, you code modify your code as:

```py
    def return_false():
        # print('Function return false') # remove this line and use print(return_false()) instead to learn that the function returns a False value
        return False
 
    def return_true():
        # print('true') # remove this too and use print(return_true()) instead
        return True

    print('test 2')
    if return_false() and return_true():
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

This code will output:

```py
    test 2
    False
```

I hope the answer was helpful...Happy codeing..:)

Comment: Great help. Your answer helped me find that my question has something to do with 'short circuit evaluation'.

Comment: Hooray..! You did some research on your own..! Happy Coding Journey..!