# Implementing pattern matching - When is the cache being used?

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

The task is to implement a simple pattern matching for the whole string where the pattern may include `.` and `*`.

The following [code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAA8mgxlov8) makes a DFS while maintaining two pointers for the text and the pattern. It also makes use of a cache for the obvious cause of not repeating work.

I was trying to test `isMatch` with several inputs but I don't see the cache is ever used ("from cache" line is never called). Can you help me show an example where the cache is being used?

Thanks

```
def isMatch(s, p):
    cache = {}

    def dfs(i, j):
        print(f"dfs was called with i={i}, j={j}")
        if (i, j) in cache:
            print((i, j), "from cache")
            return cache[(i, j)]
        
        if i >= len(s) and j >= len(p):
            return True
        if j >= len(p):
            return False

        match = i < len(s) and (s[i] == p[j] or p[j] == ".")
        if (j + 1) < len(p) and p[j+1] == "*":
            cache[(i, j)] = dfs(i, j+2) or (match and dfs(i + 1, j))
            return cache[(i, j)]

        if match:
            cache[(i, j)] = dfs(i + 1, j + 1)
            return cache[(i, j)]

        cache[(i, j)] = False
        return False

    return dfs(0, 0)


res = isMatch("aaaaaabbbbbb", "a*b*")
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

**edit: The cache is useful in this cases `"ab", "a*a*"`**

Conditions :

- The character `a` can both match the first and the second sub-expressions.
- There is no match overall

The node (1,2) can be reached from two paths

- First path explored = skip first sub-expression `(0, 0) -> (0, 2) -> (1, 2)`
- Second path explored = match first sub-expression `(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (1, 2)`

The issue here is `dfs(i, j+2)` being false while there is a match between s[i] and p[j+2].

dfs(i, j+2) will trigger dfs(i, j+4), dfs(i, j+6), ..., dfs(i, j+2*k)

dfs(i, j+4) will trigger dfs(i, j+6), ...., dfs(i, j+2*k)
...
dfs(i, j+2*k-2) will trigger  dfs(i, j+2*k)

You only need to cache `dfs(i, j+2)`

```
v = dfs(i, j+2)
cache[(i, j+2)] = v
return v or (match and dfs(i + 1, j))
```

**wrong answer : This cache is never read, regardless of s and p**

To have a cache hit you need a given tuple (x, y) with multiple paths leading from (0, 0) to (x, y). To reach (x, y) from multiple paths there need to be a branch.

So when do we branch ? Only place is

`cache[(i, j)] = dfs(i, j+2) or (match and dfs(i + 1, j))`

- When the regular expression eventually match till a repeated pattern like `a*`
- `dfs(i, j+2)` is false (if it is true, [the whole expression is already true, and due to short circuit execution, the right part of the `or` is never run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting))
- match is true : again, due to short circuit, if there is no match, the right part is not executed
- `dfs(i+1, j)` is also false. `(x, y)` cannot be both true and false.

So **The cache is theoretically hit when `s` does not match `p`.**

We store false match only when we ran out of *0 or more expression* like `a*` and the two digits don't match (eg `isMatch('a', 'b')`). At this point, the algorithm need to stop anyway, so there are no reason to cache anything.

When this happen, we are here :

```
        cache[(i, j)] = False
        return False
```

At this point, there are no more branch. Ie there is only one way to get there. So the cache is never read.

Comment: does that mean there's a bug in the author's algorithm or does this algorithm doesn't need a cache? Also, how do you explain the fact that after applying the cache mechanism, the runtime was reduced drastically to 44ms?

Comment: @Elimination my bad. I made a mistake in my analysis.