# How can I solve the below problem this is a parrot problem from codingbat?

Tags: python

We have a loud talking parrot. The `hour` parameter is the current hour time in the range 0..23. We are in trouble if the parrot is talking and the hour is before 7 or after 20. Return `True` if we are in trouble.

```
parrot_trouble(True, 6) → True
parrot_trouble(True, 7) → False
parrot_trouble(False, 6) → False
```

This is my code

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
    if talking and hour < 7 or hour > 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

my code has solve most of the problems but these last two are not working please help!

```
parrot_trouble(False, 21) → False
parrot_trouble(False, 23) → False
```

Also if you have a more efficient code please do write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break out the condition to immediately return False if it's not talking

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
    if not talking:
        return False
    return hour < 7 or hour > 20
```

Comment: when using `and` operator, does python check all conditions after get one condition `false`.

Comment: @Prasad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting

Answer (score 1):

Add parenthesis to `hour < 7 or hour > 20`. otherwise when `hours>20` ,`talking and hour < 7 or hour > 20` get `true`.

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
    if talking and (hour < 7 or hour > 20):
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(parrot_trouble(False, 21))
```

Edit:
Also, you can use (As in the first comment),

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour): 
    return talking and (hour < 7 or hour > 20)
```

Comment: You can even write it like this :
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
    return talking and (hour < 7 or hour > 20):
        return True