# Is there a one-liner "do if true" in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

In js and other languages I often perform conditional actions with `(...) && console.log('Tis True') || console.log('Tis False');`, which I like because it's simple and fits on one line.

Is there a one-liner equivalent in python3? Or do I have to break it over several lines with a boring, old `if (): ...` statement?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I think you chose the wrong duplicate. Should it not rather be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting?

Comment: You do not have to , you can chain ternary statements or use and/or . But you shouldn't

Comment: and you do not need to use () in ifs at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use `and` and `or` in the same way in python:

```
print("yes") if True else print("no")
# yes

print("yes") if False else print("no")
# no
```

Comment: If True, it prints both.

Comment: `True and not print("yes") or print("no")` could work.

Comment: I forgot that `print` returns nothing so will be falsey. Have changed the answer to use inline if/else.