# How to avoid write similar code multiple times in this situation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a code like that,

```
i = 0
l1 = ['a','b','c']
while(i < len(l1)):
    if i + 2 < len(l1):
        if  l1[i + 2] == 'c':
            print("ok")
        else:
            print("None,Error!")
    else:
        print("None,Error!")
    i += 1
```

As you can see, in the `else` part, `print("None,Error!")` are used in two times. In practice, they are very long but totally same so I want to merge them to make them simple.However, I need to check if `i+2` is out of list bound, so I cannot rewrite it to

```
if i+2 < len(l1) and l1[i + 2] == 'c':
```

Is there any idea can solve this problem?

Comment: Wait, what? Why are you asking how to *avoid* code reuse?

Comment: And you *can* rewrite it the way you say you can't.

Comment: Thanks to [short circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting), you can combine the `if`s with the `and` without problem

Comment: If you're thinking of writing code twice as "reusing" it, the standard term for that is code duplication. Code reuse refers to *not* writing similar code multiple times.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks for your reply again, so if the problem is how to avoid to write similar code mulit times....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Phu Ngo mentions, we can take advantage of [short circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting) to write

```
i = 0
l1 = ['a','b','c']
while(i < len(l1)):
    if i + 2 < len(l1) and l1[i + 2]=='c':
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("None,Error!")
    i+=1
```

If `i+2<len(l1)` is false, then the expression `l1[i + 2]=='c'` is never evaluated, which means that no error is raised.

Another solution that can be considered here is a try/except clause.

```
i = 0
l1 = ['a','b','c']
while(i < len(l1)):
    try:
        if l1[i+2]=='c':
            print("ok")
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except Exception:
        print("None,Error!")
    i+=1
```

Both result in the printouts

```
ok
None,Error!
None,Error!
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your data is large, ditch the algorithmic details and just
arrange the data in a convenient way:

```
xs = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for x1, x2 in zip(xs, xs[2:] + [None, None]):
    print("ok" if x2 == 'c' else "None,Error!")
```

Yet another illustration of the general point: one rarely
needs to iterate over a collection via indexes.