# How do I more efficiently convert a string of slices to slice objects that can then be used to slice arrays & tensors in PyTorch / NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, indices

How can I simplify this function that converts strings of slices for PyTorch / NumPy to slice list objects that can then be used to slice arrays & tensors?

The code below works, but it seems rather inefficient in terms of how many lines it takes.

```
def str_to_slice_indices(slicing_str: str):
    # Convert indices to lists
    indices = [
        [i if i else None for i in indice_set.strip().split(":")]
        for indice_set in slicing_str.strip("[]").split(",")
    ]

    # Handle Ellipsis "..."
    indices = [
        ... if index_slice == ["..."] else index_slice for index_slice in indices
    ]
    # Handle "None" values
    indices = [
        None if index_slice == ["None"] else index_slice for index_slice in indices
    ]
    # Handle single number values
    indices = [
        int(index_slice[0])
        if isinstance(index_slice, list)
        and len(index_slice) == 1
        and index_slice[0].lstrip("-").isdigit()
        else index_slice
        for index_slice in indices
    ]

    # Create indice slicing list
    indices = [
        slice(*[int(i) if i and i.lstrip("-").isdigit() else None for i in index_slice])
        if isinstance(index_slice, list)
        else index_slice
        for index_slice in indices
    ]
    return indices
```

Running the above function with an example covering the various types of inputs, give this:

```
out = str_to_slice_indices("[None, :1, 3:4, 2, :, 2:, ...]")
print(out)

# out:
# [None, slice(None, 1, None), slice(3, 4, None), 2, slice(None, None, None), slice(2, None, None), Ellipsis]
```

Comment: `eval(f'np.s_{"[None, :1, 3:4, 2, :, 2:, ...]"}')` to `eval` the string `np.s_[None, :1, 3:4, 2, :, 2:, ...]`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I that that it was bad idea to use eval as it's a massive security risk? Also, I'd like to avoid using NumPy functions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating multiple times is not necessary. The sample string has been slightly expanded to test more cases.

```py
def str2slices(s):
    d = {True: lambda e: slice(*[int(i) if i else None for i in e.split(':')]),
        'None': lambda e: None,
        '...': lambda e: ...}
    return [d.get(':' in e or e.strip(), lambda e: int(e))(e.strip()) for e in s[1:-1].split(',')]

str2slices('[None, :1, 3:4, 2, :, -10: ,::,:4:2, 1:10:2, -32,...]')
```

Output

```
[None,
 slice(None, 1, None),
 slice(3, 4, None),
 2,
 slice(None, None, None),
 slice(-10, None, None),
 slice(None, None, None),
 slice(None, 4, 2),
 slice(1, 10, 2),
 -32,
 Ellipsis]
```

The same errors as in OP's solution are caught. They don't silently change the result, but throw a `ValueError` for unsupported input.

---

#### Breakdown of the solution

Assuming `string` slicing and the `split` function are known.

With example

```py
s = '[None, :1, 3:4, 2, :, -10: ,::,:4:2, 1:10:2, -32,...]'
```

we can find `slices` with

```
[':' in e for e in s[1:-1].split(',')]
#[False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False]
```

Using `or` [short-circutting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting) we can distinguish other cases

```
[':' in e or e.strip() for e in s[1:-1].split(',')]
#['None', True, True, '2', True, True, True, True, True, '-32', '...']
```

This values can be used as keys of a `dictionary`

```
d = {True: 'slice', 'None': None, '...': ...}
[d[':' in e or e.strip()] for e in s[1:-1].split(',')]
#KeyError: '2'
```

To prevent the `KeyError` we can use the `get` method with a default value.

```
d = {True: 'slice', 'None': None, '...': ...}
[d.get(':' in e or e.strip(), 'number') for e in s[1:-1].split(',')]
#[None, 'slice', 'slice', 'number', 'slice', 'slice', 'slice', 'slice', 'slice', 'number', Ellipsis]
```

In order to process `slices`, we need to parse additional values ​​at runtime. So we use `lambdas` as dictionary values ​​to be able to call them with `(e.strip())`. Finally, we convert values ​​to `int` if necessary.

```
d = {True: lambda e: slice(*[int(i) if i else None for i in e.split(':')]),
    'None': lambda e: None,
    '...': lambda e: ...}
[d.get(':' in e or e.strip(), lambda e: int(e))(e.strip()) for e in s[1:-1].split(',')]
```

Output

```
[None,
 slice(None, 1, None),
 slice(3, 4, None),
 2,
 slice(None, None, None),
 slice(-10, None, None),
 slice(None, None, None),
 slice(None, 4, 2),
 slice(1, 10, 2),
 -32,
 Ellipsis]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Could you maybe explain a little about how your code works?

Comment: I added a short breakdown of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for adding the breakdown of the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

@Michael suggested using `eval` on a `np.s_`.

Another way to demonstrate this is to define a simple class that just accepts a `getitem` `tuple`:

```
In [83]: class Foo():
    ...:     def __getitem__(self, arg):
    ...:         print(arg)
    ...: 
In [84]: Foo()[None, :1, 3:4, 2, :, 2:, ...]
(None, slice(None, 1, None), slice(3, 4, None), 2, slice(None, None, None), slice(2, None, None), Ellipsis)
```

In normal Python usage, it's the interpreter that converts the ':::' kinds of strings into `slice` (and related objects).  And it only does so within indexing expressions.  Effectively your code tries to replicate the work that the interpreter normally does.

I haven't enough attention to the `eval` security issues to know what you have to add.  It seems that the indexing syntax is pretty restrictive as it is.

It looks like strings that don't fit the `slice` and `ellipsis` syntax are passed through unchanged and unevaluated.

```
In [90]: Foo()['if x is 1:print(x)']
if x is 1:print(x)
```

My `Foo` and `np.s_` don't try to evaluate the tuple that `__getitem__` passes to them.  `np.s_` is nearly as simple (the code is to find and read).

Normally `ast.literal_eval` is used as a 'safer' alternative to `eval`, but it only handles `strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None`