# Compare two lists and get the indices where the values are different

Tags: python, list

I would like help with the following situation
I have two lists:

Situation 1:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I need key output: **Key 4** is different

Situation 2:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I need key output: **false** -> no key is different

Situation 3:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [0, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9]
```

I need key output: **Key 1 and Key 8** is different

How could I resolve this? My array has 260 keys

Comment: Loop through the two arrays using `enumerate()` and `zip()`. If the values are different, append the index to the result list. At the end, print the result list. If it's empty, say that no keys are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indices. Use [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting) and the fact that an empty list is falsy to get `False`:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

out = [i for i,(e1,e2) in enumerate(zip(a,b)) if e1!=e2] or False
```

output:

```
[4]
```

output for example #2: `False`

output for example #3: `[1, 8]`

Comment: @Gustavo that's why I provided the links to the documentation ;) `zip` enables to iterate several iterables in parallel, enumerate enables to get items of an iterable along with their indices.

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `itertools.compress`. Compare the lists to check difference in values, pass the result of the comparison to `compress` which will pick-up only the `True` ones.

```
from itertools import compress

a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

result = tuple(compress(a, map(int.__ne__, a, b)))

if not result:
    print(False)
else:
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is really good, but for an approach which doesn't need zip/enumerate, loop like this:

```
lista = []
listb = []
unequal_keys = []
for idx in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[idx] != listb[idx]:
        unequal_keys.append(idx)

if unequal_keys == []:
    print(False)
else:
    print(unequal_keys)
```

I recommend learning new techniques and using build ins like zip and enumerate though. They are much more pythonic and faster!