# Check if string is None, empty or has spaces only

Tags: python, string

What's the Pythonic way of checking whether a string is `None`, empty or has only whitespace (tabs, spaces, etc)? Right now I'm using the following bool check:

```
s is None or not s.strip()
```

..but was wondering if there's a more *elegant* / Pythonic way to perform the same check. It may seem easy but the following are the different issues I found with this:

- `isspace()` returns False if the string is empty.
- A bool of string that has spaces is `True` in Python.
- We cannot call any method, such as `isspace()` or `strip()`, on a `None` object.

Comment: That looks reasonable, though perhaps you could think about ways to exclude `None` by other means earlier in the code.

Comment: Thinking about it the opposite way: `if s and s.strip(): do_something_with_s()`

Answer (score 4):

The only difference I can see is doing:

```
not s or not s.strip()
```

This has a little benefit over your original way that `not s` will [short-circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting) for both `None` and an empty string. Then `not s.strip()` will finish off for only spaces.

Your `s is None` will only short-circuit for `None` obviously and then `not s.strip()` will check for empty or only spaces.

Comment: One possible improvement could be doing `set(s)!={" "}` instead of `not s.strip()`, but that's getting a bit bikesheddy