# why while condition failing here

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to solve a problem: find middle node of a linked list with following code ( and it works)

```
s = f = head
while f and f.next:
  s = s.next
  f = f.next.next
return s
```

but when I accidentally wrote this it failed:

```
        s = f = head
        while f.next and f:
            s = s.next
            f = f.next.next
        return s
```

with error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
    while f.next and f:
```

I am trying to find out why this behavior, both loops check if f and f.next are not None. why order matters here?

Comment: Boolean `and` short circuits, meaning if the first condition is `False` the second condition is never checked. In your second test you check `f.next` before checking if `f` is `None`. In the first you check `if f` first so if it's `None`  `f.next` is never attempted and you don't get the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting